# Reputation for unregistered account?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts, unregistered-users

I noticed this question pop up on the StackOverflow homepage: [Disable multi select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527493/disable-multi-select)

The OP seems to have answered his own question (it was a clarification, actually, but that's common for new users), but the rep displayed for the two seems to be different.

[image]

I clicked through both, and ended up finding two different *unregistered* users. When did we start giving unregistered users profile page and reps? Even stranger, is that the user seems to have **two** of them, maybe through two different logins, I don't know. Here's one of them, the one that answered his own question and apparently got one upvote for that.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When did we start giving unregistered users profile page and reps?

We always have. They can't vote, though, until they register. If they decide to register they will retain their rep.

> Even stranger, is that the user seems to have two of them, maybe through two different logins, I don't know.

Unregistered users don't have logins. They only enter their name and email (which is **NOT** used as a the openid login, it's only used as the avatar and to contact the user if needed), and then a cookie is set that identifies their temporary account. Unless they register they have no way to log back in to the same account if they lose the cookie.

Comment: That's odd... I've always thought unregistered users get a gray username with no account and a generic 'person' display picture

Comment: @Yi That happens if an account gets deleted, or if a post is migrated to another site that the user doesn't have an account on