# If more users could vote, would they engage more? Testing 1 reputation voting on some sites

Tags: discussion, voting, privileges, testing

**Update April 3rd, 2024**

[We have posted an update on the status of this experiment on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429682/revisiting-the-voting-requirements-test). Please leave any feedback, questions, or critiques on that post.

---

**TL;DR:** We are interested in finding 2-3 Stack Exchange sites willing to volunteer to test lowering the reputation required to upvote and downvote to 1 so that we can understand how this change impacts participation on sites. This test will be run with direct communication between the company and the moderation teams and we will be monitoring user behavior during the tests for specific indications that adjustments to tooling or ending the test may be necessary. If successful, we'd like to expand this change to the network.

### What is the background of this experiment?

We've long understood that many users find it difficult to participate on Stack Exchange in some ways. We have collected user research over the years indicating that many people have struggled to participate because they feel the restrictions about who can vote are too limiting and prevents them from indicating when questions or answers are good or bad. While one of the core concepts of Stack Exchange is that anyone should be able to freely access the content and have the opportunity to ask, answer, or edit, this openness doesn't extend to other privileges on the sites.

We’ve historically used reputation as a way to prevent misuse, but in doing so we’ve made it hard for people to participate at all without creating content. By removing or changing some of these barriers to participation, we hope to spur participation and engagement - including posting, voting, and curation/moderation. The goal of this particular project is to understand the impact of removing the reputation required to upvote and downvote.

Reputation is a simplistic way to prevent abuse, but it doesn't reflect actual risk or a user's experience with the site or subject. By understanding the impact of removing the reputation barrier, **we can find more targeted ways to address abuse for users of all reputation levels rather than sticking to the rather simplistic solution of relying on a reputation barrier to prevent wider-spread misuse of votes**.

We have these restrictions in place for a variety of reasons, but the core concept behind all of them is to prevent misuse and protect the perceived value of the content on the sites. We *do not* want to make it more difficult for mods and community members to moderate content on the sites, nor do we want to see people inappropriately voting on content and thus reducing the value of the library of information.

As such, while removing the reputation required to vote is a five minute change to our privilege settings, we've spent the past few months understanding the potential risks of this change and adjusting our plans for this project. Based on voluminous thoughtful feedback from moderators across the network, we've made improvements to some moderator tools and have enhancements in the works based on their recommendations. While these changes aren't going to prevent all issues, they should make identifying and acting on them simpler.

Before we build additional moderator tooling and before we expand this test beyond these initial test sites, we want to see this change implemented on a few sites to see how it impacts engagement. It's important for us to hear from sites directly and see these changes in action to learn how changing the reputation to 1 changes voting behavior or if it adds an unreasonable amount of work for moderators and CMs to investigate. Our goal is to use this information to guide our future efforts, identify any necessary additional moderation tools, and validate whether these voting updates lead to increased engagement.

### What would change for sites participating in this test?

There are three main privilege changes happening here as part of our test:

- Reputation required to cast upvotes is changing from 15 to 1
- Reputation required to cast downvotes is changing from 125 to 1
- The 1 reputation cost to downvote answers will be removed

We will notify logged-in users with <125 rep to let them know that they can vote with a popup.

To understand motivations for new downvoters, the first few downvotes from a <125-rep user would *require* them to explain their downvote - this information will not be posted anywhere, but will instead be collected by our research team and bucketed into categories so that we can better understand reasons people downvote. While we expect that many voters may just enter gibberish, we feel like we'll get at least some usable information.

While we have considered various options for this test, since our goal is to be as permissive as possible, we want to start with opening voting to everyone. Regarding removing the reputation required to downvote and the cost to downvote answers, this is a situation where we want to balance the system. Users don't like receiving downvotes, but they are vital to a quality-based system. When we're looking at things like an aging content base, we recognize that giving even passive users the opportunity to say "this answer doesn't work" may help combat that to some extent.

One major thing is not changing - **having a registered account will be required for voting**. Unregistered accounts and logged-out users will not be granted the ability to vote. Additionally, users who are suspended will still not be able to vote during their suspension.

### What are the risks and challenges of this test?

Over the last few months, moderators have shared their feedback and concerns about this experiment, which have been related to changes to vote quality, disproportional increases in vote fraud, and difficulty identifying handling sock puppets with the existing moderation tools. We understand those concerns and have done our best to adjust our test plan to find a path forward that allows us to test our hypothesis without risking negatively impacting the entire network by suddenly changing voting practices. Much of our test plan is designed to catch cases the moderators have identified and give room for communication throughout the test.

To address their concerns about identifying vote fraud and sock puppetry, we've made various improvements over the last three months to these tools. While we generally avoid speaking too publicly about moderator tooling, here are some of the general improvements we've made or are planning to make:

- We have overhauled a moderator dashboard that draws attention to potentially suspicious votes and made it easier to find (live on site for use).
- We have overhauled the Moderator Messaging and CM escalation UI to show mods and CMs more history about the user in the message context (live on site for use).
- We are making it easier for moderators to find and act on sock rings (in design phase).
- We are making it easier to escalate groups of suspicious votes for CM review and invalidation (in design phase).

We're still working out some bugs in these tools but the feedback we've gotten indicates the updates are well-received and they're looking forward to further improvements.

### What is the test plan?

We want to find 2-3 established sites that are willing to volunteer for this test. Preferably, these will be larger sites that have moderators willing to work directly with the members of the Community Enablement team, the team dedicated to this project whose primary responsibility for the past year has been creating and improving moderator and community management tooling.

Our specific plans for data collection include:

- Reviewing existing voting and participation data and analyzing the impact of the changes in collaboration with site moderators and community members
- Conducting user research to assess perceptions of post quality before and after this change
- Analyzing voting differences based on various factors including:

  - Reputation
  - Account age
  - Final outcome of the post - e.g. if a question is closed or deleted and why, or an answer is deleted
- Keeping an eye out for changes in users going undetected by tools that use reputation as a signal to block participation

  - This includes both built-in tools like SpamRam, as well as community-created ones like SmokeDetector.
- Setting guidance before the test that will help us identify cases where rolling back the changes or making other adjustments are necessary.

We intend to run this project as transparently as we can, considering it relates directly to voting, which is something that we try to keep as private as possible. Due to the sensitivity of this data, some of the communication will be on a Private Team with the moderators of these sites. We will ensure there is open communication of publicly shareable information with the sites directly through the moderators and staff working on this project.

Because our test includes regular monitoring and clear guidance on when reverting the change is the best course of action, our plan is to retain these changes unless we see evidence they're causing negative impacts that we can't address quickly by making changes to tooling or automations.

After the test has been running for a month, we will create a report to share with here on Meta Stack Exchange before we determine the next steps for this project.

#### Which sites will be chosen?

This is a big change, and we would really love to find sites willing to volunteer - we don't want to force any sites into this test group. While we have sites we think would be good options and we'll be reaching out to them directly, we encourage members of sites to discuss whether they're interested in participating in this test on child meta sites. We would like to have some of the larger sites participate and will likely lean towards them as the impacts of these changes will probably be seen more quickly than on very low-activity sites.

### Conclusions / asks

Removing the reputation barrier to voting for all users is a change we feel will lead to more users being able to indicate post quality and usefulness, but we recognize that it will require a lot of care to ensure that we are educating voters about when to vote and encouraging them to follow acceptable voting practices while also preventing or removing votes that were cast inappropriately.

We recognize that you may have many questions or concerns about this project and that this post may seem like it doesn't include a lot of specifics about the risks of this change. In writing this question, we're trying to focus on the test to keep it short(er) - the version of this that was posted on the Stack Moderators Team three weeks ago was significantly longer, as it responded to many of the mods' specific concerns.

- If you think a site you participate in would be willing to test this, let us know in a comment so that we can reach out on the child meta site or start the meta discussion and flag the question to request mods to feature it on the site. We can create an answer with links to site discussions network wide.
- If you have questions, please ask them in answers so that we can respond to them individually. It really helps if you can try to limit answers to one primary concern.

We have spent over three months reviewing and re-evaluating our plans for this project based on a huge amount of very helpful feedback from moderators over the course of two questions on the mod team to get to where we are now. We really appreciate the feedback they shared with us because we want to investigate this change in a way that works to avoid negative impacts to the sites.

Comment: "We really appreciate the feedback they shared with us because we want to investigate this change in a way that works to avoid negative impacts to the sites." - our feedback saying the tooling isn't ready for the increase in abuse this will lead to apparently didn't make the cut

Comment: @Zoe I understand that you and others have concerns - we've specifically made huge changes to this project plan to address those concerns and have clearly stated that we have additional changes in design and have planned to make further changes but need some data to know what changes are needed. This post doesn't invalidate those concerns - it actually recognizes them and validates them.

Comment: You're still _massively_ underestimating the tooling requirements, particularly for SO. Your plan still doesn't include massively extended and improved automated tools. The current automatic vote invalidation system is a potato, and the abuse vectors for evading detection are well-known. You're dumping a massive increase in workload on us, and not doing close to enough to reduce, automate, and improve the workflow for dealing with vote fraud (but _especially_ reduce and automate)

Comment: Remember, even a 1% increase on small sites might just be a couple cases, but on SO, it's hundreds, if not thousands (partly depending on how you count it) of cases per week, most of which will have to be manually handled when the brand new sock rings that can be established with no cost and with a disgusting number of users casting few enough votes to remain undetected start firing up

Comment: Many low-rep users don't understand how SO works, don't understand how to ask a good question, and, a lesser proportion, don't accept and/or acknowledge an answer / respond to requests for clarification. How much confidence do you have re: voting for helpful answers. Yeah, I'm a little jaded on this. I also echo the sentiments re increased abuse and moderator effort.

Comment: I generally expect that upvoting things that are useful, and downvoting things that aren't is a fairly common thing across the web... not something unique to SO that users who previously couldn't vote at all won't be able to grasp. I welcome this change and hope the issues it may cause can be addressed.

Comment: Have you (or other SE staff involved with this) read [the feedback here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391527/1081494)?

Comment: @cocomac Yes, we've read that. I've even commented on it when I cleaned up the comments. While many of the answers there are valid here, many of them apply to the breadth of privilege changes rather than only the ones related to voting, which is what this project focuses on. We have no plans to change any other privileges as part of this change.

Comment: @QHarr I'd argue that equating voting to the complexity involved in creating and improving posts isn't quite right. While I wouldn't go so far as to say that voting is *simple*, by comparison to asking a question, it's a breeze. I think that it'd be far easier to educate users to vote properly and let them than it would ever be to educate them in how to create content or edit so they can come up with an idea for a question or answer or submit a bunch of edit suggestions just to earn reputation and then be allowed to vote. To me, that makes little sense.

Comment: @Zoe I understand your worries. A major point of this test is to better understand what tools are needed. This is why I would deter us from testing on SO - while we need bigger sites, most sites have a fraction of the flag queues and suspicious votes list we see on SO. I really don't want to burden the SO mods further while the tools are still being developed. But I do believe that on most other sites, we'd be able to monitor votes throughout the test without creating a burden for those sites' mods.

Comment: I'm concerned that new users may not be able to recognize a good answer from a bad one and might upvote convenient answers over correct answers. I'm all for engagement, but I hope that SE will take steps to check if "average voter behavior" is significantly affected by this change, which would be a significant red flag wrt the quality of the new votes.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the data for, say, a specific week, comparing the voting of registered user "feedback" votes vs registered user actual votes, keeping in mind that actual votes are somewhat skewed toward upvoting given the different thresholds and cost of downvoting answers. It can't be compared 1:1, because users who get hit with "you can't do that" likely don't do it again, but maybe people seeing where those votes land in the current voting environment may alleviate some fears.

Comment: @KevinB I have looked at that with a tool we have that's more exact than the 10k tools and, even on SO, the numbers weren't particularly concerning to me - from memory - something around 20% additional votes with up/down vote ratios similar to voters with permissions but I avoid leaning on it too hard for the reasons you state and also because those votes aren't unique by user - the same person can click the vote button on the same post multiple times or up- and downvote the post, so those votes aren't 1-to-1 with actual votes.

Comment: @A.R. The comparisons you mention we should do are in the list of data we're going to gather because we understand this concern. I've gotten a lot of mentions of exactly that concern and I seriously have to ask - does having 15 or 125 reputation actually mean you know how to vote? I feel like there's a fallacy in arguments like this because of an assumption that privileged users vote "correctly" and that unprivileged users can't (excluding overt vote misuse). I think we should instead consider that "correct" voting isn't as uniform as we expect and address that for all users.

Comment: Some people don't downvote to avoid the point penalty for downvoting. The new users often remove questions that get a couple of downvotes wasting whatever time anyone has placed on them

Comment: Hey @MarkSchultheiss Could you explain in more detail what you're trying to say with your statements? The first one definitely relates here but it's unclear whether you think that's good or bad. The second sentence seems more related to whether or not a user can delete a question than who can vote but if I'm misunderstanding, please let me know.

Comment: @Catija "_I really don't want to burden the SO mods further while the tools are still being developed_" is that just a personal position with no bearings on the company's decision making? Or does that hold that kind of weight?

Comment: @starball I'm the CM liaison for the team working on this project, my primary function is advisory and support. That said, my voice has been heard along with the concerns of moderators over the last few months so while I don't make decisions, I trust that I have some sway.

Comment: @starball additionally, we're looking for sites to volunteer with willing moderators to work with us. If the SO community really wanted to participate and the bulk of the mods were on board, that might outweigh my concerns... but... how likely is that? I'd guess not very.

Comment: Why not have the required explanation for downvotes be visible? That way, the community can already learn from this experiment as it is happening, and it will teach new users that their actions have consequences that are seen and felt by everyone. This will allow for more direct guidance.

Comment: You can ask the [Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/) community. As you, Catija, know, we're a small community that would benefit from more participation, but I'm not sure if we're of a size that is considered 'helpful' in this context.

Comment: @Joachim Since the current plan for this explanation UX is for the test period only, keeping it internal doesn't require moderation tooling integration and there's reason to expect these comments might not be particularly polite. Requiring explanations for downvotes has been one of the most common requests on MSE and MSO and is near-universally unpopular with core meta community members - to some extent I want to avoid that very much. I think we would be willing to share the picked-over responses and stats *somewhere*, but not on the downvoted post itself.

Comment: I think this would be a big benefit for really small sites in different ways than big ones, @Joachim , but you're right that A&C is likely a bit smaller than we would want for this phase of the project. Thanks for the invitation, though! I'll keep y'all in mind.

Comment: Readers of M, P&T will know how much I abhor unexplained dvs. Which will increase in number when all and sundry are allowed to dish them out, Dished out mainly by folk who probably are pretty clueless as to how the site works. But given powers for no effort - we all know where that leads! Let sleeping dogs lie; if it ain't broke, etc. No explanations is like marking a kid's work wrong, but never explaining why it's so. No-one learns anything.

Comment: @Tim obligatory link to [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are requests suggesting such negatively received?](/q/325416/997587)

Comment: Somewhere tucked deep in the back of my mind, there is a SEDE query that can reveal "symbolic" votes on your posts. I could be imagining this whole thing, but I thought all users could register a vote, it's just that the reputation barrier determines whether it is counted or not. If this is correct, I remember being horrified to see 10s if not 100s of votes against my posts, both questions and answers. Was this just a fever dream?

Comment: @roganjosh not a fever dream see [the PostFeedback table schema](/a/2678/997587). "_Collects up and down votes from anonymous visitor and/or unregistered users_". There's also the 10k mod-tools for seeing posts with interesting anonymous vote ratios.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution The closest this post gets is the test plan. Many of the success and failure metrics will be determined once the sites have been selected. The test plan specifically includes various checks on voting practices and user research to assess whether there is a change in perception post quality before and after the change. We outline more checks related to the things you mention than engagement. Also,  I'm personally interested in whether voting leads to participation in other moderation or contribution activities rather than just voting alone.

Comment: @A.R. *"I'm concerned that new users may not be able to recognize a good answer from a bad one and might upvote convenient answers over correct answers."* If you have ever looked at the HNQ, this should not be a concern, it should be a known fact. It happens all the time, and if users earning the association bonus are free to do it already, I don't see any difference in letting every new user do it.

Comment: @Catija  Reference to my statement regarding removed questions.  Often (very often) new users put in questions that lack clarity, code or some such and also often they get comments from others as clarification questions or "missing code to reproduce" or other often symptomatic of not reading the site guidance they get pointed to the "How to ask..." post - as a result they after a few of these get downvoted questions which they see as a reputation hit.  I have often the seen them react by deleting the question then they ask a NEW question often with same clarity issues in part. CONT:

Comment: CONT: then the effort to comment and vote by OTHER users gets lost and the same cycle occurs on the NEW question leading to further negative experience by both users.  Action: research deleted questions and comment/vote time cycles and NEW questions shortly after perhaps.  I know doing that is time consuming because I do that in my job with data sets that can insert logs in the millions in short time frames but I have to do so.

Comment: @Nij HNQ has limits. The scale of the voting this proposal allows is the problem. Also the spammers that will get free reign.

Comment: What is so important about users "engaging more"? I think at some point you have to choose between content quantity and quality.  The current voting system seems to strike a healthy balance - why then are you pushing for more quantity?

Comment: @Butthose Voting on most sites is on a downward trend from the data I've seen, as is the percentage of users with the ability to vote. I invite you to check out some of my responses to answers below because I think there's a fallacy in your statement -  our current system doesn't actually judge whether someone can vote accurately or not. I know that framing this as "increasing engagement" can seem like we've pulled away from content quality in search of views - but voting is the core way we determine content quality and if few people can vote, who's assuring good content rises to the top?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thanks - that's what I thought you were getting at. While there are some improvements I have on my backlog to get built in that might address your points, and I'm well aware that this happens on many sites, I'm not sure how this relates to the subject at hand. This wouldn't impact when a user could delete their own question.

Comment: Why do you even need to find volunteers, wouldnt the results be similar to an SO Teams? (with rose tinted glasses since probably less sock puppetry)

Comment: @Catija - did you just call me Butt Hose?? Lol!  Just kidding, it's funny though.  I believe you but I think you have to admit that the network has been making a slew of detrimental changes and ignoring the community feedback for a while now.  That certainly has caused ME to draw back a bit. I guess those new buttons aren't helping as much as was expected.  I still hate clicking them. But yeah, let's let some 0 reppers click them to make up for it.

Comment: Could you run this experiment for a couple weeks, but keep track of the votes cast by these low-rep users, and when the experiment is over, undo all of those votes (after collecting whatever data you need)?

Comment: @Catija ONLY going by the title "engagement" when they get frustrated they leave so engagement = 0;  More downvotes to unaccustomed users means more leave due to this human factor - not new info obviously to anyone at SO. These are hard problems made harder by large culture differences of users.

Comment: Voting rings, yea, it is the front line defense against voting rings.

Comment: I thought unregistered users _could_ currently vote, if they got to 15 reputation. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Sayse every team I've been on (I think) has had a "upvote each other so everyone can get voting privileges" Q&A. basically, a sanctioned voting ring. I don't see how you'd get pure data for teams because of that.

Comment: @Sayse I think attributing Teams data to public sites would be a ... poor choice. The average Team is a group of coworkers within a company - people you may have personal relationships with. Also, you actually still need 125 reputation on a Team to downvote, so even if we set voting practices aside, it wouldn't give us any info about downvotes.

Comment: @starball I'm guessing the Teams you're on are largely centered around SE/SO-centric groups who may use downvotes quite frequently. In that sense, your statement is valid - and I've seen them on such Teams myself. But *most* Teams have very little downvoting or closing or other moderation of posts.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 As far as I'm aware, unregistered users can not vote, regardless of reputation. My searching for a reference turned up [this from 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62619/284336), but I have no reason to doubt that the policy has changed, despite it not appearing in other FAQs about voting (that I could find)

Comment: @Catija "participation in other moderation or contribution activities rather than just voting alone" I feel like this would be a second order effect (cool they let me vote, so let's find out what else I can do). I'd be more concerned with direct impacts. Voting is a quality assessment. Post quality isn't directly influenced by it but post order would be. Result of this experiment could be a better or worse ordering where high quality posts are more or less often on top. Maybe voting is a limiting factor and we need more votes to get a better ordering. But I'm not sure about that.

Comment: FWIW, [we are discussing whether CrossValidated wants to volunteer here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6578/1352). Currently, we have 8 nays and 1 aye. The discussion there mirrors the one here.

Comment: The voting system is already overburdened in the functionality that it encapsulates. It is the sole unmoderated, public marker of quality, interest, accuracy and also often stands as proxy for feedback on the user/poster's behavior. This breadth already points to a broken system and that is before one considers the 'point' values assigned to it and the privileges those points afford the user. A single highly rated question regardless of its quality will afford the poster vastly more power on the site than a user who diligently closes duplicates for years.

Comment: Maybe worth removing the vote cap also. There's no point me getting an additional 50 votes per answer when I'm hitting the cap pretty much daily anyway.

Comment: @starball It's 100 for downvote privs. You can set R = 15 for upvote.

Comment: @Richard if we get to the point where privileges are no longer tied to rep and rep becomes a recognition of the community's reception of the content a user has created, I'd be more likely to consider that option. But I'm pretty sure such a change would have an outsized impact on highly active users who rep cap regularly and probably don't really need additional incentives to participate.

Comment: The one place where a version of this would definitely be a good idea is Meta Stack Exchange. Make your MSE rep tied to the network total rep (remove MSE-independent rep) and then make upvotes and downvotes free, but keep the rep thresholds for voting up and down the same.

Comment: Why don't you start by lowering the voting thresholds for this Meta and see how it goes first?   And if you don't want to do that, why do you think it's a good idea to inflict it on the SEs?

Comment: @FuzzyChef We want to get info about how voting is used and misused when the reputation is lower. I actually think changing it on MSE would be really useful because right now voting here only reflects what people with rep think. The 10k tools show, in fact, that [this question would be much higher scored as these very users upvote it 2:1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtalF.png). The main reason I wouldn't want it to be tested here is that the test is designed to understand the impact on **main** sites. Data we collect here wouldn't apply to Main sites because voting on meta is different.

Comment: And before y'all misunderstand me as saying "NEWS FLASH!!! Catija thinks users with 1 rep should have a voice on MSE"... Well... I mean... I'm not *not* saying that. But I'm also tired of people implying 1 rep users aren't "real" users or don't care about the platform and content. Some don't... but would people who don't care follow a link in the bulletin and try to vote? Many care. They just don't necessarily care to create content. And votes on Meta don't mean much. I'm more likely to make a decision based on the strength of an argument than the score of the post.

Comment: Yeah, I was just struck by the irony that, on a thread about lowering rep for up/down voting, I don't have enough rep to vote (despite being a reviewer/editor on two SEs).  Meta-meta has very tight controls over who can post and vote.

Comment: If user participation is the primary objective, then perhaps participation points should be awarded. Five points for logging in to a Stack Exchange site. Five points for each comment left with no loss of points if comments are deleted or removed. For every thousand points, one receives a $10 Visa or Mastercard gift card.

Comment: The voting system suffers from a flaw - lots of people will see a good question and simply not be moved to vote on it. Speaking of the mathematics stack exchange here, many good questions get left behind in the dust because they were too niche to receive a quick obvious answer or massive popular attention (e.g. early undergrad or integral or basic real analysis questions get very large, undue favourable attention, or things that touch on a common but basic confusion). We do need more engagement, but not from new accounts - think of the bot issues

Comment: @Butthosenewbuttonsthough.. it is debatable how good the current balance is

Comment: If you want to apply s such a change, first test in on mother Meta itself. You may get the glimpses of the consequences.

Comment: while I don't quite understand what user16145658 is saying, it brings up a question for me: what is considered "inappropriate voting" here and how is it determined? does it just mean serial voting / voting fraud detected based on the serial/fraudulent voting detection tools? Or does it extend to voting practices that are simply discouraged / strongly discouraged but still currently acceptable, and to detection methods like "user said in their vote explanation that they are revenge downvoting"? Is the definition covered by the CoC like https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct/disruptive-use ?

Comment: Pick any tag on any page you want, wait until it has "10 new questions", how many of them are clear, useful **and** show research effort? how many are unclear/not useful **or** lack research effort? This is one of the reasons I don't vote because its very often that none of them meet the upvote criteria and half meet the downvote criteria and all that negativity is bad for mental health

Comment: @QHarr - this thread is getting a little long so I've not read everything yet so sorry if you've already addressed this. I have faith in newbies being able to vote for good answers. At the end of the day, if they found an answer helpful and it sorted their issue, even if it's not perfect, it's worth a vote in my book. I'd have more concerns with them being able to vote on questions

Comment: Is the purpose of SE to generate clicks and participation? or is to generate high-quality and accurate information about topics. I think we all know the answer is the latter. Allowing essentially anyone to vote might increase revenue through greater activity, but why should someone with no expertise (and only a strong opinion or emotion) be able to vote? This is a dumb idea that directly works against the mission of SE. Big downvote from me

Comment: @theforestecologist earning 15 or 125 rep doesn't somehow prove someone has expertise... nor does it increase the likelihood that they do.

Comment: When push comes to shove, is the priority in getting an increase in engagement, or an increase in the _quality_ of the engagement? I'm leaving the door open to arguments that the latter might be achieved through the former in the long run - but the general pushback you're receiving here is that the current actions seem to strive for the former at the cost of the latter. Being clear on the priorities here will help address those concerns.

Comment: @KevinB don't I know it! You're right. Experts make up a small percentage of any population on SE. However, the sub-5 rep population appears to have the lowest percentage of experts. That's a lot of people voting for the wrong reasons! Look at any SE site: the number of 1-rep users is often 100s of times greater than even the 10+ users. It would just be a flood of [even more] poor quality voting from people who haven't taken the tour and don't know what a "good" question or answer looks like.

Comment: To me the most difficult barrier to overcome was being unable to comment, because it was impossible to ask for clarification. But personally I have not problem with voting being a privilege.

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque you can always comment on your own posts - for posts by others, quite often, especially with older posts, there's little point to comments, especially if OP had left or lost interest in the network long ago

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Considering that the entire purpose of the site was to avoid paywalled content only being accessible to an elite few "professionals", that seems to me a significantly larger change than merely allowing more people to vote. Millions of people are professionals but have not participated, so your statement isn't even factual - there is no correlation between site participation and expertise and to continue to assert that there is, is fallacy.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek maybe my recollection is wrong, but does that mean you can't comment on answers to your question? Because I remember breathing a sigh of relief when getting the commenting privilege. It's been a few years.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer it's hard to really understand you unless you explain why you think this change would be harmful. you could either write up an answer post doing so, or vote up other answer posts that you agree with.

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque you can comment on any place where comments are allowed on a question you've asked.

Comment: By nature of this being on meta, opinion will inevitably be biased towards people who use StackExchange quite a lot. In terms of % of users, most would probably support this.

Comment: Of course they would! But mainly to uv/dv q and a. Which I don't believe would enhance much on SE. From personal experience, it takes some time to get accustomed to the vagaries and workings in any case, so a bad move, imo.

Comment: On MathOverflow, I've noticed a number of questions lately with 1 or 2 upvotes that I don't think are worthy of any upvotes, and probably wouldn't have gotten any several years ago.  Which means, IMO, at least some number of newer users are voting in different ways.

Comment: @Kimball I'm not sure I understand - they're the same people who've been voting - we haven't actually made any changes yet. If you feel like they're voting inappropriately, then the current reputation barriers don't actually prevent problematic voting, they just hide it because there's less of it. One of the goals of this test is to figure that out but...

Comment: @Catija I just mean that, on MathOverflow, I think unwarranted upvoting has already been increasing over the past year or two.  So I suspect, for that site, lowering barriers would exacerbate this.  (Of course it could just be my opinion on what a quality post is is too old-fashioned.)

Comment: Is there any point in continuing discussion here now that @Catija got laid off in the most recent round of lay-offs? Is any other SE staff member going to take over? Is this experiment still on-going?

Comment: And by the way, has any site actually volunteered for the experiment?

Comment: I'd spoken to Cat about volunteering Pets - partially cause we're probably small enough to both both benefit and contain any damage, and partially cause I *personally* had a great working relationship with Catija. I'm still processing and deciding what I should tell my fellow mods and community and how we'd want to proceed

Comment: @user3840170 Yes: [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16891/should-arqade-opt-in-to-the-1-reputation-voting-experiment), [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3850/should-we-volunteer-to-test-1-reputation-voting), potentially Pets as JG mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: @Mazura ... uh... what? I'm really confused what you mean by that.

Comment: You clearly didn't read the question, @Mazura - this change would allow everyone, regardless of reputation, to both up and downvote any post they like - even the question title says just "vote", not "upvote". I'm not really sure why you're commenting without doing the bare minimum of even attempting to understand the proposed change.

Comment: ... "it's been a month"? understatement of the year. I'm not doing anything any more. :P

Answer (score 307):

I totally understand why you're asking for volunteer sites, instead of forcing this on any site that doesn't want it, which would have gone down way worse with the mods/communities of those sites and with the broader SE community. *But*, I just thought of a potential drawback of that approach.

### Any site willing to volunteer for this experiment is probably a site less likely to suffer negative consequences.

Thinking about some of the sites I'm familiar with, I can think of one site that would never volunteer for this, due to too many people willing to try too much abuse, and another site that's much more peaceful and might potentially volunteer in order to get vote numbers up with a relatively low risk of widespread abuse.

### Please account for this kind of "selection bias" when analysing results.

If one site volunteers for having 1-rep voting and it goes reasonably well, that doesn't mean it would go similarly well on another site, with a completely different community! The sites most likely to suffer from it are also those least likely to volunteer for it, while any site willing to take the risk of volunteering is probably one that's risking less by doing so. Essentially, *by asking for volunteers, you may end up skewing the results towards more positive outcomes*.

Maybe this is obvious, but I thought it was worth mentioning explicitly ...

Comment: In the longer term, if the experiment doesn't point to total disaster for any site willing to allow 1-rep voting, maybe this could be **opt-in for individual sites**, or maybe even **vote thresholds could be adjusted** according to each site's needs. Many small sites suffer from not having enough voting, but rolling out such a change on high-traffic sites is likely to lead to chaos.

Comment: Right now I am far more worried about this than I am about any short-term effects on whatever sites end up as guinea pigs. Or, more generally that the test will not surface problems that an eventual network-wide rollout will.

Comment: This is a fair point. There's a lot that testing on 2-3 sites will tell us but there's a lot that it won't. I think the impacts of this change will vary significantly depending on the categories any one site is in. E.G. - I would be cautious about changing this on a more subjective site like Parenting or Workplace if we'd only checked it on primarily objective sites. I have personal experience with the impact of HNQ status on IPS and that was just users who have the association bonus... that said, it would have been interesting to see the impact if the bonus granted both up- and downvotes.

Comment: While discussing eventual rollout plans is jumping ahead somewhat since we haven't even identified a list of sites to test on, let alone seen the impacts of the change, this sort of answer will help us be more thoughtful about pacing that rollout if initial tests prove positive results. I appreciate you calling this out if only so I can respond to acknowledge it.

Comment: I think this approach does not take into account that *One size does not fit all* or to put it another way reputation algorithms *do not scale* across 180+ different sites.

Comment: Couldn't agree more.  Unfortunately, that's been explicitly rejected as a reason to scale privilege levels to site size in the past.  I suspect that all the SO proper mods/members that previously *objected* to the idea that one size does not fit all and hamstrung smaller sites with their pseudo-democratic mass (in many cases likely because they did not think the small spin-offs should exist at all) may change their tune in the near future. :)

Comment: (+1) excellent point, my Lord Dragon.

Answer (score 257):

##### If more users could vote, would they engage more?

Of course. It's like putting a bowl full with candies in front of an hungry kid.

##### Is this good?

No. I really don't think so. Here are couple of reasons:

- The eager 1-rep users will start by downvoting each and every post of each and every user who dared posting a comment with any hint of criticism on their posts.
- Those users will then upvote blindly the first 20 (or whatever the votes limit is) posts they see.

There is a good reason why Stack Overflow cofounder decided to put in place reputation threshold for voting. That reason has never changed.

I understand the desperate times. I really do. And yes, desperate times call for desperate measures, and that's just one of many Stack Exchange is doing in this new odd AI Era. But I'm just saying: it's a mistake. It won't work in the way you think/hope it will.

Comment: Hopefully, the results of this experiment conducted on 2-3 guinea pig sites will bear out what you predict (I agree) and they won't then take it further to the whole network.

Comment: These are exactly the sorts of things we'll be checking for. The former will already be removed by our system automatically and the latter is something we already see - we get occasional reports from mods about users who are dumping votes on sites in pursuit of badges. While we expect these will be more common, that doesn't mean they're not already happening. Seeing how common they are during these tests will help us prioritize either improving or supplementing automations or adding additional tools.

Comment: As a CM, I see these situations happening already and would love to have better ways to handle them or be able to avoid manually handling them at all. It's valid to draw our attention to these outcomes but I also think we need to address these concerns in a measured way. Preventing all low-rep users from voting because some will misuse those votes doesn't seem reasonable to me and earning reputation doesn't equate to knowing how to use votes. I'd rather address actual misuse. It's certainly *easier* to use rep but that doesn't make it the right solution.

Comment: I'm willing to accept that we're underestimating the negative impact of this change and that's why we'll be monitoring this and looking for abuse that's both overt and subtle. By the same token, I think many people overestimate the negative impact of this - which I don't begrudge! Either way, making decisions based on assumptions and mental images of users - whether angelic or devilish - risks us making mistakes. That's why we want to see what actually happens.

Comment: @Catija You have tools that can detect if one user is regularly downvoting another user, correct? And such votes are automatically undone. But is there any sort of punishment for the user that does this?

Comment: @trlkly We have a variety of tools for detecting targeted votes. Some remove the votes automatically while others are added to a tool mods can investigate more closely or contact the CM team to request a deeper investigation and possible vote invalidation. This may lead to a mod message or suspension for the voer. For automatic invalidations, we don't notify mods or the voter when these occur. I think notifying mods in cases of extreme or repeated invalidations would be a nice improvement, and would let them look for other voting issues and contact or suspend the user if deemed appropriate.

Comment: This is exactly the point of the experiment: to find out if that's true.

Comment: IMHO the biggest problem of SO is that bad answers are not downvoted enough, so that would be actually good.

Comment: *"If more users could vote, would they engage more?"* ─ Even this is not so simple. The engagement SE wants (i.e. people posting good content) is what would earn people the reputation they need to be able to vote. So that engagement is currently incentivised by rewarding people who do it with voting privileges. Then why should we expect engagement to go up when one of the incentives is removed?

Comment: @kaya3 The voters are not necessarily the only people this change will cause to engage more. If someone spends time on a good answer and earns no upvotes, they may decide it's not worth it to take the time any more. Now we have fewer people creating good content. By having more people with the ability to vote, a higher percentage of consumers on the site will be able to indicate whether the posts are good which may lead fewer people to get frustrated that their efforts are unrecognized.

Comment: I think that users being allowed to vote is a good idea.

Comment: @Agent_L "Bad answers" is subjective though. What about the polarizing answers that some users find helpful and others find unhelpful? Should we discourage the contributors of those answers? Sometimes people post good content but receive all kinds of flak for it not being in the format that SE is accustomed to, and reasons of that nature.

Comment: @Mentalist Yes, that's precisely what the up/down system is meant to show. Remember that SO is not for people who ask questions, nor for those who answer them. Majority of traffic is passive readers, so the prime objective should be to provide them with unbiased review of presented answers. High number of both up and downvotes is a conveying "this is controversial" message. We're not after **any** content, we're after **helpful** content.

Comment: @Randal'Thor It seems a bit wrong to hope for the negative case to be true.

Comment: I read somewhere the other day that SO traffic has declined 50% in recent years. This may be due to the constant push to dumb down the site and allow trash content to be generated. This is a site for programmers -- it should not be dumbed down. If you dumb it down, you let non-programmers mess it up for everyone else. For me, this is a professional resource and over the past few years it has become less and less relevant, correct, and useful. I would pay, real money, hundreds per year, for something like SO but without all the crap like this 'test'.

Answer (score 145):

### Can those sites have the association bonus disabled/turned off?

One major concern that I (and likely others) share is that this may (and likely will) lead to voting rings and (rule breaking) sockpuppet accounts. As an added measure to prevent the effects of that spilling over to other sites, can that bonus be disabled, please?

Comment: We've had several discussions both with Mods and internally about the Association Bonus and we're definitely thinking about it. Based on my last conversation about it, we see several options for this and have documentation of those options. The main thing I'd like to state is that while I agree this change might exacerbate problems caused by the Association Bonus, I think many of y'all would agree that it's flawed as it is and needs to be overhauled entirely. It's a great concept but it leads to many problems. ... comment thread incoming. (Apologies)

Comment: A bit of background - you many not realize but I actually wrote the initial version of the [Association Bonus FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work/303118#303118) and still have enough of the characters to be the top contributor on the wiki answer. While that doesn't mean I know all of the random stuff it gets misused for, I probably know more than most people. While I have a mental plan for what the Bonus V2 should look like - or at least how the Bonus can be changed, these things haven't been dummy checked.

Comment: It really peeves me when I see users dump the bonus on a bounty, award it, and run delete their profile... only to come back and do it again. Similarly, someone who posts a question or answer that gets downvoted to the point they've lost all of their rep can delete their profile and start over with the bonus intact. The Bonus is attached to the user's *account* rather than requiring a consistent amount of reputation, which means a user who deletes all of their profiles and starts over from scratch will have 101 rep everywhere and it's super confusing.

Comment: Users who have votes invalidated and drop below the 200 rep needed do not *lose* the bonus because once earned, forever kept. So, while some of my proposed solutions (these are personal ideas for the Bonus and not anything we've committed to, to be clear) may be half-baked so I'm not going to cover them here, they're based on a good understanding of those issues and a wish to address them. This is what we need in any situation. A good FR isn't a really great explanation of a cool feature - at its core, it's an explanation of a problem so that a PM can understand the struggle.

Comment: So, how does this relate here? Our current plan is to keep an eye on users earning the bonus but not prevent it. While this is not set in stone, I'm not sure how simple it'd be for us to remove a site from being able to award the bonus. While we've discussed it, it seems like this might be more complicated than one might expect because it is awarded on a network-wide basis. We'd also have to ensure that blocking it wouldn't prevent users from having the bonus if earned on another site added to their rep on one of the test sites.

Comment: This is likely one of those things where we'll have a mitigation in mind if we see this is actually an avenue being used to circumvent restrictions on other sites to post spam or otherwise misbehave but, if not, retaining the bonus is our preferred option. As with rep requirements to vote, restricting everyone because of a minority of bad actors is something we'd like to move away from. We want to focus on the bad actors rather than relying on simple solutions that impact the majority of users participating as we would expect.

Comment: Alternative suggestions: [Let's prevent association bonus abuse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391913/323179)

Comment: @Catija There was a time when participation in Stack Overflow for Teams awarded the association bonus. (While this was fixed in 2020, it regressed around 2021, and continued to be an issue until last year when Teams was completely dissociated from the public network.) Once it became possible for users to create a Team for free, there were users who abused it to gain the bonus rights on their account by exploiting the free voting privileges given in Teams sites. I'd highly look into how often this was exploited back when this hole existed and let that factor into your decision.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I'm not sure how easy it would be to find that data. I don't remember whether the network annotation referenced the Team specifically or just attributed it to SO in general - though users with <200 rep on SO would be a decent indicator. That said, because this existed for all Teams users, I don't actually think I need data to confidently state that there would have been orders of magnitude more people who earned the bonus on a Team and never participated on the public sites than people who intentionally created Teams to abuse this loophole.

Comment: If this change is ever implemented site-wide, then there will be less need for the association bonus in the first place.

Comment: @Catija Firstly, thank you for the response. I do have a few questions, though. (1)  You've stated that SE will be monitoring users earning the bonus - has that monitoring plan been shared with diamond moderators? (I'm specifically _not_ asking you to publicly reveal it to avoid divulging information about voting ring detection). (2) Can the mitigation plan (for if too many users are creating voting rings) be determined _in advance_ and shared (publicly)? Thanks!

Comment: @cocomac 1 - The Mod Team post I shared with them a month ago specifically mentions the bonus and my explanation in that post was shorter than my comments here but contained the same core points. That's as specific as the plan is currently. We plan to hold off on finalizing the test plan (as a whole) until sites have been selected and we've had the opportunity to refine the metrics with the mods on those sites. 2 - I can't commit to sharing the mitigation plan publicly at this point but I will keep it in mind as we move forward.

Comment: I have suggested practically the same (I haven't read this prior to posting my answer, I'm sorry), but I just presented the argument differently: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393276/289691.

Comment: @Catija on the subject of Assoc Bonus changes: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56701225#56701225 (and slightly further down https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56701363#56701363) Also, that fraud scenario you describe sounds horrifying--I had no idea the bonus was not tracked permanently. I 100% support dev hours being put toward shoring up that kind of abuse--deletion of accounts should be 'soft' deletion that still tracks whether an association bonus has been awarded before, and not award if an account is deleted or not.

Comment: There's a lot about profile deletion that could use some investigation, @TylerH - there's actually a few improvements that have been made that are less visible publicly but make it much easier to address situations where a user profile gets accidentally deleted (rare but happens). We used to have to have the user create a new profile and now we just have an undo deletion button. There are potentially cases where someone can/should legitimately have the association bonus reinstated after a profile deletion but there should be a way to flag that account to indicate when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Late post 2 @TylerH - I wouldn't be in favor of requiring multiples of 200 rep to get the bonus on each additional site - if nothing else, that would require the user decide (no take-backs) which site they want to grant the bonus to, which seems a bit... a lot. It would also hamper community projects like Charcoal, which relies on the bonus to allow flagging. I know there are issues (I know you see that) but the solutions are going to take some thought - I'd love a discussion here on MSE about how to *reimagine* the Bonus to address these issues (slightly different than Laurel's).

Comment: @Catija "*that would require the user decide (no take-backs) which site they want to grant the bonus to, which seems a bit... a lot.*" I mean, it's _free rep_. Having some more stringent requirements for it seems fine to me. But I have not done any actual investigation into the concerns (e.g. re: Charcoal flagging)--the thought only popped into my head when I posted about it in SOCVR). If I ever have time I'll consider writing up something about reimagining the bonus in a way that addresses abuse of it while not hampering other efforts like Charcoal.

Comment: @TylerH Sure, no worries! I think that the goal right now isn't to solve the problem with the Bonus so much as it's to recognize that there is a problem and start figuring out how best we can address the issues while retaining the benefits. To some degree, this may change drastically as we move away from relying on reputation to grant privileges. In a distant future where privileges are based on taking trainings and doing tasks that are peer-reviewed, we could consider whether earning an individual privilege on one site would grant it network-wide without granting based on rep only. :)

Comment: To use Charcoal as an example, we could have a per-site training for how to flag on that site for various reasons (assuming the trainings are customized), and then a Flag spam/abuse network-wide privilege that was granted based on a training related to identifying spam and abusive content. Who knows. Could be cool... could also be hard. But there's so much room to change the status-quo.

Comment: @Catija Yeah, I find it hard, for example, to think of a reason why 1000 helpful flags (or 100+ helpful mod flags) on one site would not automatically indicate (very strongly) that you should have at least _some_ additional flagging capabilities network-wide, for example.

Answer (score 100):

Whatever poor sites decide to volunteer to be a guinea pig for this, they're going to be in for a world of hurt with limited hope to clean up afterwards.

Voting is one of *the* most subjective activities we do here, and there are people who already don't downvote questions based on their own belief system, not on the actual fact that a question or answer is bad.

The idea of opening the flood gates to *literally everyone* to vote on content is probably THE single riskiest experiment that you could hope to accomplish.  In its wake would be the abrupt end of sensible curation.

The plan also does underpin and highlight a key dependency on the community to help with detecting patterns of bad behavior, which is...sure, that's what they're good at, but it'd be nice to have the assurance that they're on board with your changes here.

But more fundamentally, one thing I don't see called out nearly loudly enough is

## how you plan to educate users on what to upvote, what to downvote and what *not* to upvote or downvote

and this is a problem that is so fundamental that it pains me to feel that I need to explain it.

I don't see myself having a future on this network if this experiment actually does succeed.  I can't accept a world in which we just let everybody come here and rate content based on how they *feel*.

Comment: "I don't see myself having a future on this network if this experiment actually does succeed." What do you mean by "succeed"? If the experiment shows that lowering thresholds increases voting and participation with little to no negative effects, doesn't that improve the network? And isn't this experiment exactly the right way to figure that out?

Comment: @LShaver: I think the "succeed" that I had in mind was their intent to simply lower reputation thresholds to 1.  I feel like this has been floating around for a long time as something they wanted to do [(case in point)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391527/175248) but now, they are trying to do so more broadly.  Whatever internal metrics they have of "no negative effects" are still questionable to see if they could be achieved, since...well, motivated actors could easily rig this system in their favor with consequences that would last longer than the experiment.

Comment: I'd say the current UI and guidance for how to vote are either easy-to-miss or inadequate/confusing - if not both - and not flexible enough for the entire network. Onboarding is something we generally need to improve and how to vote *on SE sites* is one aspect of that. That said, the stated purpose of votes is to indicate whether that post is "useful". On very objective sites - the "useful" guidance is actually more subjective to me than voting. On primarily subjective sites, vote practices become very obscure and confusing and really more of a set of guidelines and recommendations.

Comment: *(for brevity, "bad" is defined here to mean "uninformed/problematic" but non-fraudulent votes)* Your concerns about an increase in the volume of "bad" votes are valid and as far as I'm aware, we accept that's likely the case, so I don't want these comments to seem dismissive of that or defensive. There's definitely an expectation that the *quantity* will increase (more votes implies more "bad" votes) but what this test is designed to determine is whether the **percentage** of "bad" votes will be higher. I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: Votes can mean a plethora of things across the internet - and even within this network - but it's not clear to me whether voting rules here for the average voter are particularly prescriptive or arcane or absolute such that someone who has never posted on a site would be unable/unlikely to vote in an expected manner without going through a training. Do you have evidence that low-rep users would be more likely to vote based on how they *feel* rather than whether an answer works than current voters?

Comment: @Catija:  To the last point about evidence - it's a search away with "hate stackoverflow downvotes" or "never downvoting on stack overflow", and I know there were several Meta discussions about users on this very site who simply never downvote anything.  The manifesto is all the same - it's not based on any actual concrete metric or any concrete rationale other than "they don't like it", without the same understanding that voting is *intended* to help us rank the usefulness of a question or answer.  Instead, you get blogs and articles about how the votes make people "feel".

Comment: @Catija:  So, if you let everyone vote, now you let everyone's feelings take over in place of logic and reason.  I cannot see how this ends any worse for the network now that people who have "felt oppressed" at how voting "worked against them" can finally "do something about it".

Comment: @Catija:  The charge though really should be to improve the guidance on voting.  We've sorely needed that for well over a decade and it simply hasn't come.  This means that while most site veterans understand the thrust of what voting is, non-veterans are going to disregard that *with no consequence*.  I don't see how it's exactly *fair* to punish someone for not following guidelines if the guidelines were so unclear they managed to get their keyboard stuck in their toaster oven.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something core to your argument that isn't in your post explicitly and that's leaving me confused so maybe I need a bit more help understanding - how does people who already have the privilege not downvoting correlate to this change? No one can be forced or coerced to vote - up or down and, other than addressing socks and voting rings and some other cases, we don't really have any way to judge whether votes should be removed. People have weird rules for why they vote and no amount of education will change that if they really feel their method is the "right" one.

Comment: Regardless, we have years of baseline voting on most sites to compare to votes from these newly-privileged users to see if there's actually a difference in behavior and what that difference is. We'll be able to dig into cases where vote habits differ to see if these new voters are actually voting in a way that conflicts with site norms and - by being in close communication with site mods - we'll be able to have an expert on hand to indicate whether those vote trends are concerning. While we'd be willing to investigate cases community members flagged, we wouldn't rely on them alone.

Comment: Why would it be hard to undo? The system should still know who had enough rep to vote under the current system, and keeps track of all votes. So it should be able to retroactively remove those votes if the decision is made to pull back. I'm all for testing assumptions with empirical data rather than taking on faith that a certain idea was correct because the founders came up with it.

Comment: @Catija:  I'm not exactly addressing people who already have the privilege.  I'm more addressing people who don't and are unfamiliar with how the voting scheme is intended to work.  I'll agree that people have weird rules and vote in that fashion, but in general the main intent is to vote to rank quality content.  I would prefer if the company invested more in educating users about the system rather than wanting to make it open season on the most fundamental thing we can do on the network - rank content.

Comment: @trlkly:  Where do I mention "undo"?  I mention "clean-up". Undoing something is something that's isolated to typically one or two things, with the limited impact being only impactful to one or two actors.  Voting and privilege spider out in such a way that the overall impact of cleaning things up would be *a lot harder*.  You get enough people to upvote/downvote something, now you've impacted privileges, maybe bounties, and a lot of that has a cascading effect on how the site overall is used.  There would be some undeniable level of legitimate activity, so I could see hesitancy to revert it.

Comment: @trlkly:  So just keeping track of it doesn't buy you anything, because now you could quite easily screw up an entire user's experience of a network site in such a way that really can't be remedied by "this was an experiment, soz, need to roll it back now".

Comment: @Makoto I didn't say you said "undo." But that is a form of cleanup, and one that Stack Exchange tends to use. It very much does not limit its impact to one or two actors. Nor is the legitimacy of actions considered. For example, if a Question is removed, , it doesn't matter if you put in a very good Answer. You still lose all those points. You gave a bounty? You get it back. You accepted a bounty? You lose it. And that's a very small example of things--they've done site-wide recalculations before.

Comment: @Makoto I tried to suggest a [solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393281/1373045) to the problem you presented on the implementation of the scheme. Also I agree with you.

Answer (score 97):

**Voting is for winnowing and content curation. Are one-rep users really experienced enough to do that effectively?**

The current thresholds are there for a reason. Simply removing or reducing them would be mayhem.

---

One tiny thing that *may* help would be to make users take the Tour to receive the ability to vote. That way, new users at least have an idea of what to do with their votes, though whether they pay it any heed is uncertain.

Comment: I agree.  Even users who know what to do with their votes don't know enough about the community to know which posts are suitable for that community and which aren't.  That comes only with time spent as part of the community.  I would actually be OK with substituting another metric for reputation, like reading and engaging with post, but it's hard to imagine something easy to measure but not easily gamed—so why not go with the gameable metric we've already got?

Comment: I really like the tour idea; obviously some folks will click through anything we give them without reading, but it still sounds like a cool idea, and a decent way to get the tour in front of more eyeballs.

Comment: I'm in favor of giving users a comprehensive test before granting them privileges.  Let them sit through a queue of scenarios (if they don't have rep).  Prove to the community that they know when to upvote, downvote, closevote, flag, answer and comment.

Comment: There's a badge for taking the tour, right? The voting privilege could be tied to that.

Comment: It would also weed out a lot of spammers (if the tour is spam bot resistant), at least the lazy ones.

Answer (score 73):

I predict chaos if either of the two down voting proposals are adopted. A lot of first time users have little understanding of the site or its purpose. Having a small cost of down voting makes people think a bit before doing so. And requiring some experience also guards against malicious users.

Some down votes on sites I use (GOAT at two of them) are because people just don't want to hear the answer, even if it is correct. Even now, I suspect some down voting on questions is because people just don't agree that the question is important enough to them, irrespective of its importance to the OP.

Some more of the down votes I see have comments that suggest that a word or two in an answer caused someone to object, even though the answer itself was fine (valuable).

I have less to say about up voting, but a middle range option might be to have new users with little reputation only add, say 5 rep to an upvoted post rather than 10.

And if the changes to down voting are made then the site would need to be especially vigilant about serial down voting, possibly removing users who do it and reversing their votes. But that seems like a nightmare. This would especially apply to removing any cost of down voting.

Think of the bots.

As a side, I find the down voting criteria (This answer is not useful) to be extremely weak advice. Useful to who, exactly. Why, exactly. My personal criteria for down voting answers is whether the advice would be dangerous for the OP to follow. But I don't down vote answers giving different advice than I would give otherwise.

For many things a flag will do. For others, a comment is enough, and it may cause a writer to re-think their advice. A down vote alone gives little guidance to a writer unless there are a lot of them and even then, some answers with a lot of down votes are still valuable. I have a few highly down voted answers at Academia, and I'll still stand by the advice.

---

Actual *engagement* with the sites is when people ask and answer questions, not so much when they vote, which doesn't actually even require reading posts. An alternative "carrot" for engagement might be an automatic rep boost for the first few (3-5) questions and/or answers made by individuals. It might lead to junk, of course, but might be worth a test. It might even get low rep long term users more engaged, not just newcomers. It would also get new users closer to the current limits and permit voting themselves.

To try to avoid junk, this proposal might award, say 50, rep points for the first five question posts on a site provided that the question itself has both a positive vote count and an answer with a positive vote count. And similarly for any of the first five answers with a positive count.

Comment: I mean, it's fairly well known at this point that even people who understand the purpose of the site and what it is looking for refrain from downvoting answers they think are wrong or not useful due to the rep cost.

Comment: @KevinB - upon what do you base that hypothesis/wild claim? Citations please.

Comment: From 13 years of people saying as much on MSO.

Comment: That said, there's a lot of answers here with various opinions on things that prevent people from casting downvotes. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398537/what-can-we-do-to-encourage-downvoting?page=1&tab=modifieddesc#tab-top

Comment: The cost to downvote has never affected my choice to downvote. It's so minimal that it has always seemed like it might as well not be there. The only time it would have affected me was if I just didn't have enough rep. Number go up isn't really all that much of an incentive: the reason why I like my rep is because it shows me people find my posts useful. That doesn't change if I spend my points.

Comment: The G.O.A.T. is the user that currently has the highest rep on a site: Greatest of All Time. But, of course it is a temporary thing as one can be passed. I will likely lose the designation on one of those sites. It is just a fun thing here.

Comment: A question for the mods and staff: Should I make my engagement proposal at the end of this a separate meta post?

Comment: I've seen posts on Politics SE already being voted into Hades because the person dared to suggest that Donald Trump may not actually be evil. Removing barriers to downvotes would intensify that happening.

Comment: @trlkly but you've probably also never used sock puppet to milk association bonuses for bounties or serial downvotes of people commenting on your answers. Or any of the other things that the main proposal in this Post has been criticised for.

Comment: I think this discussion shows some major differences between sites. Reputation on MSO, even more so on Mathoverflow is considered precious, you need to provide meaning mathematical insight to get it, on MO it even needs to be meaningful in the eyes of a professional mathematician. Even if an answer is objectively wrong people often prefer to comment hoping for a fix rather than downvote. On the other hand, upvotes on politics often simply follow for matching political views and similarly people downvote because the politically disagree.

Answer (score 73):

One of the big reasons that I use and contribute to Stack Exchange sites is *because of* the barriers to entry.  Those barriers aren't difficult to overcome for someone who genuinely wants to participate, and they're generally effective at keeping the bots and trolls at bay.  The SE network is one of the few places left where you can get trustworthy answers from knowledgeable people.  Other sites (e.g. Reddit) allow anyone to vote on anything and they quickly become breeding grounds for trolls.  Voting ends up reflecting what people personally *like* instead of what's *accurate*, so sites become self-reinforcing echo chambers and you can never tell what information you can believe.  Users need to understand how the site works and how it's different from other places before they start skewing vote numbers (i.e., the quality indicators that comprise most of the SE sites' intrinsic value).

If you enable this feature on the Politics.SE page, it will devolve into Propaganda.SE faster than you can imagine.  You cannot possibly build up moderator tools that will counteract the power of state-sponsored troll farms run by world leaders that can't handle any sort of criticism.  I'd also expect heavy troll pressure on History.SE as well as any of the religious sub-sites.  I highly recommend not implementing this sort of change on those sites at any point for any reason.

Comment: Re *"it will devolve into Propaganda.SE"*: Yes, just look at  YouTube comments (it doesn't matter what the subject is (if the video or channel has a significant number of views)).

Comment: I really like this callout; it sounds important to recognize not just the impact of the change on existing members of the communities and _individual_ bad actors, but also larger-scale "raid"-style attacks as well... it's way easier for (e.g.) a swarm of folks on Reddit to dogpile voting on content here without the rep-based vote limits in place... Maybe we'll need protected questions to also block out low-rep votes, as well as answers.

Comment: Like [the answer Rand wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393137/284336) warning us about selection bias, you give a specific example of a site that would need special treatment, which is a useful reminder, too. There are a few sites like Politics that need additional barriers to participation - and many of them already do. This is because our privilege system and other site settings are rarely hard-coded. For example, while most sites allow users to create unregistered accounts, Politics does not. CMs often adjust these settings as-needed by request of sites.

Comment: Some sites actually have *more* permissive policies than the standard - for example some set rep required for meta participation to 1 (vs. 5). This project won't lead to the site settings for reputation required to up- and down-vote being removed and all sites being hard coded into the same bucket. While I think most sites fall into one category, I'd estimate 10-20% need overrides. The added benefit of this system is that we can determine a network default that works for most but override the sites that need it.

Answer (score 66):

Will more users vote if you give more users the right to vote? Yes, yes they will. That is, however, not at all what would be desired, or likely, even tolerable.

Looking back at the initiatives put forth by the administration in the recent years, I can only recall those designed to increase *user retention* and not the quality of content. This is a metric that a social network would be interested in. A place where anyone can say anything, no matter how demonstrably false it is. Stack Exchange is designed to be the opposite of that.

As a meritocracy, we are not interested in as many people as possible clicking the buttons. We are interested in competent people clicking the buttons, and others not so much. Which, and that scares me the most, is likely no good for a *social network* manager, because the *number of users engaged* is countable and reportable as a managerial achievement, whereas the quality of said users is much harder to quantify.

It is absolutely to be expected that there exist people who do not qualify for a job.
I was born without either physical or psychological capacity to play basketball professionally, and if I showed up at an NBA office complaining that I felt excluded at the basketball field and asking them to put it in the rules that the basketball hoops must be lower and larger, I would be laughed out, and rightly so.

I understand that this mindset goes against the principle that anyone can be anything. That principle, however, is verifiably false, whereas the success of Stack Exchange, built on a different principle, is verifiably true. I would hate to witness a real and good thing to fade away because of a false and not so good idea.

With that being said, do note that the hoop that we have for full-fledged voting is not very high-hanging at all. Pretty much anyone who can communicate with sense can clear it in a very short time. Removing even that would serve no real purpose other than inviting people to your house you didn't really want to invite after all.

Comment: I don't think that the mindset *does* go against "anyone can be anything" (which I more or less believe, even though I also agree with this post).  I think it only goes against the mindset that "everyone is already everything."  New users of an SE site are not yet ready to be informed participants in its culture.  They absolutely *can* be, but they aren't yet.  And the way that they show they're ready is by earning some reputation.  (Well, really, by participating.  But hopefully, if they do so in a way that fits in with the existing community, they'll earn reputation along the way.)

Comment: Stack Exchange is asynchronous. We don't care whether it takes you five seconds or five hours to come to a conclusion; all we care about is how good the conclusion is. Most people can get a basketball into a hoop, given sufficient tools and sufficient time; likewise, most people can contribute to Stack Exchange.

Comment: The analogy may be flawed, but the main point still stands: It should primarily be ensured that the quality of the votes by low-reputation users is up to SE's standards (which is not trivial to do, but for starters just comparing their votes against those of high-rep users would probably be very insightful; significant statistical deviations would have to be sampled, and the samples manually investigated), not that their engagement increases.

Comment: I'll note that the main reason I stopped answering questions on SO is because the majority of my answers never got any votes (and not because they were bad - if other answers existed, they also did not get votes, and sometimes I even got comments from the OP saying thanks and it fixed it!).  Votes on Stack Exchange are very "heavy", compared to reddit or Facebook or whatever, which is good in some ways but also removes a lot of motivation for people to help in low-traffic places.  The argument for heavily gating votes would be stronger if folks did sufficiently much voting, but they do not.

Comment: It's unclear whether you're implying that this project is only interested in user retention/creation. Assuming that you are, while I can understand that assumption based on the context of your answer, it fails to recognize that *how* we are encouraging users to engage in the context of *this* project is quite different than pure user retention. I will agree we have made many design decisions that focus on "vanity metrics". When Jobs was on SO, we built creating a Jobs profile into the account creation profile - which caused confusion particularly for users who just wanted to ask a question.

Comment: This is just one (old) example where we prioritized increasing adoption of a product (Jobs) over the primary needs of users (asking a question). I do not put this change to voting privileges in that same bucket for a variety of reasons, most notably that the kind of engagement we are looking to impact will specifically increase the volume of content quality signals we are getting without increasing the prevalence of low-quality signal. More accounts or visits per day is a vanity metric, more (good) votes is a quality metric.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov's experience is not unique. The number of voters on SO is quite low and the people who do create content often get discouraged because they don't see their posts being well-received. This varies by site and (within SO at least) by tag as each group have different voting habits. Some sites have users who cast many votes per day while other sites have active users who vote infrequently... I don't have data for this but, anecdotally, I have talked to some people who save all or most of their daily votes to downvote for quality reasons (legitimately) and rarely upvote because of it.

Comment: If this is a meritocracy as you claim, I feel it's a terrible one. Where SE fails as a meritocracy is that it measures achievement based on - at most - three skills (asking, answering and editing) and treats all other skills as second-class or lower since they have no impact on privileges. Merit is awarded by people who have  already earned merit and - as you and many people who have thousands of merit points say, earning the ability to judge merit here is so "easy", they don't understand why people complain about the restrictions. I say this as someone with >100k points on MSE.

Comment: Your comparison to the "anyone can be anything" principle is flawed because you rely on extreme cases that are easy for everyone to agree with. You paint all low-rep users as lacking in merit but SE merit is not absolutely needed to judge whether content here is good or be a subject matter expertise. A more accurate depiction of this situation is someone who plays basketball professionally in one country not being able to do so in the NBA because they don't have a visa. Paperwork does not define someone's skills. Ability does.

Comment: To take your analogy further - remember how I mentioned that we only care about three skills?  Saying "*Pretty much anyone who can communicate with sense can clear it in a very short time.*" is the equivalent to saying "*You're hired as an NBA referee but you can't actually start until you've scored six points in a regular season game. We don't care whether you score two three-pointers, three two-pointers, or six free throws, you just need six points.*" This makes no sense to me. Not being willing or able to play the game and score points has no bearing on voting ability.

Comment: A good meritocracy is one that takes all of a system's needs into account and rewards people for being good at those tasks. Players play, coaches coach, refs blow whistles, cheer squads cheer, janitors clean up after the game, mascots make trampoline-based dunk shots. Forcing everyone to succeed at the same role before they can start specializing is a bad meritocracy.

Comment: @Catija but the voting system as it stands doesn't even begin to represent a good meritocracy. A single highly rated question regardless of its quality will afford the poster vastly more privileges on the site than a user that spends their time closing duplicates will ever gain. The fact that active curation by normal users (flagging, commenting with related questions, voting to close as duplicates) doesn't increase standing makes the brokenness of the voting system even more frustrating. And the fact that downvoting blatantly inaccurate questions impacts the voter more than the poster...

Comment: @pilchard yes, that's my point. My comments above are specifically focused on showing that is the case. While I opted to focus on different aspects of why the meritocracy is bad, if I were writing a complete persuasive essay on it rather than comments, points like yours would have been included very prominently.

Comment: @Catija I think you get that NBA analogy wrong. Think more of it like the NBA needs tons of referees but for some reason cannot carry a full ability test for each one of them. Instead they tell you that if you want to be a referee you need ten previous referee's loose approval. Of course that's not perfect, as some will give their approval more easily than other, but if you simply remove this entry barrier then anybody can declare themself a referee. While having a few bad referees in the NBA isn't a big deal, in a place where the fake accounts can outnumber the real ones that's bad.

Answer (score 65):

> If more users could vote, would they engage more? Testing 1 reputation voting on some sites

#### 1-rep users can already cast votes.

This is the message shown to all logged-in users who have less than 125 reputation on a given site:

[image: modal window indicating feedback has been recorded for voting attempts below 125 reputation]

Note this part of the message:

> **your feedback has been recorded**

What about this data which you have been collecting for some ~13 years doesn't satisfy your needs?

Why can't that unsatisfied need be rectified by just changing the text of the modal rather than granting a dangerous privilege to people with zero experience on the site?

You could say something like

[image: A new modal saying "Thanks! Your feedback has been recorded, but you need at least 125 reputation for your vote to be visible]

or something similar.

#### The impact of this proposed change is an unfair and untenable asymmetrical shift in power toward 1 rep users.

Currently, users of the site who have skin in the game (read: who answer or ask questions) can rest easy knowing that if someone wants to downvote them or upvote them, that someone will have at least also provided some kind of contribution. They've submitted *some* quality content at least *somewhere* on the network, either directly on that same site, or so much on another site that they've earned the association bonus on another site.

It's very easy to create an account, and if there's no requirement to learn how to use the site before that account can cast votes, you will see a huge increase in people casting votes for the wrong reasons, especially fraudulent ones. Voting rings will become a major issue for mod teams to deal with, more so than they already are (ask Stack Overflow mods if they want to increase the voting ring work they are doing by an order of magnitude).

As for removing the 1-rep cost for downvoting answers, I'm hesitant that will lead to more meaningful use. There's already no cost for downvoting *questions*, and those don't get downvoted nearly enough. I worry we'll just see people competitively downvoting other answers to questions they've posted their own answer to.

Comment: Remember the "Thanks" reaction? Kevin B suggested something similar to your proposal in [this extremely well-received comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/241211#comment775689_398369).

Comment: Haha. Turns out [I responded to him there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/241211#comment776375_398369): _"I kind of like that idea. Occasionally I upvote an answer on an SE I'm not a part of (because I forget it goes to `/dev/null`). It'd be nice if those three people on Seasoned Advice got upvotes if I ever did join, but the chances are slim. Here's the worry I have: it's going to provoke more cycles of battle between vote rings and vote-ring-detectors."_

Comment: **Note** - this statement has proven to be incorrect. See statement below for update. <strike>If I remember correctly, it does not record who cast the vote. As such, the same user can have multiple upvotes, downvotes or both for a single post. The focus of recording the feedback is for that 10k page which is designed to highlight posts that get lots of feedback or different feedback than votes or... whatever.  There's not 13 years of data from this that's actually usable in the way you're indicating.</strike>

Comment: @Catija Oh no! I thought this idea was good. It still could be good if you did start recording the user who took the action.

Comment: @Catija So the modal has been lying to us this whole time... great :-( I thought it was recorded and shown as aggregate information in the data dump as well. Here's my request for y'all to start actually logging that information...

Comment: I think it's *technically* accurate... we do track the feedback. It doesn't claim that we tie it to the voter. You can interpret it that way, so I understand feeling lied to, but I'm not sure how to phrase it better - my five minute (not-serious) attempt is:  "Vote attempts from unprivileged users are thrown in a bucket of anonymized feedback about this post. You need *n* reputation for your vote to be actually be recorded and linked to your (possibly non-existent) account." (Hopefully this is met in the lighthearted way it's intended but let me know if otherwise).

Comment: @Catija How will the 1-rep users notice that something has changed? Contrary to most people here, I worry that normal users will not notice they have gained this new power and therefore will fail to use it. Meanwhile, experienced users wishing to use the change maliciously will definitely know about it. So the data will be skewed towards malicious usage. To avoid this outcome it would be necessary to make sure that the UI actually advertises this change in a way people understand.

Comment: @Nemo from the question : "We will notify logged-in users with <125 rep to let them know that they can vote with a popup."

Comment: @Catija if it is tracked without association to a user/person, then that means 1 rep users or logged-out users can "vote" a thousand times for some content to have that content show up on the data dumps, inflating the value some content gets in the data dump that isn't reflective of reality. This is obviously small fries compared to other issues the team is facing on their to-do list, but "the integrity/accuracy of post scores in our publicly available data dumps is, well, less than we thought" is certainly _a_ problem that ought to be addressed eventually.

Comment: @Catija but back to the matter at hand, I truly do think allowing 1-rep users to click the vote buttons and have it stick, but not having it change the visible score, is a much better way to implement this.

Comment: @Catija but how will that notification/pop-up be different from what they got so far?

Comment: @Nemo So far they haven't had the option to vote on posts and have it "stick" (read: have it count). Now they will, hence the notification.

Comment: @TylerH regarding the data dumps - they are one of the areas I'm least knowledgeable about, so I don't know how impactful it is. I also think it's unlikely that users are sitting around for hours giving tons of feedback on one post. I obviously don't know but it seems like a very odd choice.

Comment: @Nemo the current UI only appears when someone tries to vote. The new UI will show up on page load (question pages only) for anyone who hasn't already dismissed it and has under 125 reputation. I think it's a pretty standard way to let users know about new features. It's how we currently notify them about other privileges they unlock.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It seems plausible that being notified upon page load, as opposed to after clicking the upvote button, will be perceived as something new even by users who've already attempted to vote before.

Comment: Rather than removing my prior statement and avoid it looking conflicting, I'd like to correct it. **We *do* track who cast vote attempts, both by user ID (if logged in) and IP (if not).** Additionally, as far as I can tell, we only retain one vote per user/IP, though I'm not sure how we handle someone who upvotes and downvotes. I'm not certain where I picked up the idea that we don't track who cast the votes. I would not have stated it if I hadn't had some confirmation of it at some point. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 42):

When it comes to the cost of casting downvotes on answers, would that change be retroactive, resulting in some users receiving a sudden influx of rep when this is added, and then losing it again if the test were to be disabled? Or will correct reputation levels be retained by calculating rep based on before experiment vs during.

Comment: Would be interesting if people were suddenly getting thousands of rep back...

Comment: I feel that retroactive changes for rep would be a disaster.

Comment: I feel the delta of the change will be *very* small for the overwhelming majority of users, and the users where the delta would be large have enough rep that it doesn't matter anyway, or, they and the community will benefit from them gaining access to new tools. On SO i stand to gain anywhere from 30-40k rep if it were done retroactively there... but... i already have 90k. who cares about 30-40k more at that point.

Comment: This is an open question internally, both for the duration of the test and retroactively if we make this change permanent on sites. I don't think we have a "right" answer here, so my preference would be to retain the rep loss at least initially and have a discussion here on MSE about what the best path forward is. If we did nothing, I would guess that the rep recalc would take the current site setting and apply it to past votes, which would remove the cost retroactively.

Comment: One note, @KevinB While you have that many downvotes, more than half are on questions. - it's worth considering how many of those downvoted answers have been deleted - the answer being deleted should refund the rep anyway, right? So if half of the answers you downvoted were subsequently deleted, you'd probably see closer to 10k than 30k-40k. Feel free to check my math! :D

Comment: @KevinB for what it's worth, you can go to the /reputation page and then count the -1 rep changes.

Comment: Ah, right. so 11k, that's far better than i was expecting, so even less of an issue ;)

Answer (score 36):

If the end goal is to increase engagement, is allowing them to upvote and downvote posts with 1 rep the only option we had? And why did we directly reduce the reputation requirement to bare minimum? We should have taken a gradual approach (first reduce a bit, see the results and then decide if it should be reduced more or stay the same).

We could have done other stuff like (just my personal opinion):

- letting them post comments everywhere with low rep (not 1, perhaps 40).
- letting them downvote with perhaps 50 rep
- set bounties with perhaps 55 rep

And why a one size fits all approach for a testing phase? All communities would love to see increase in engagement, but I guess they know their communities better than us. Instead of us directly deciding 1 rep as the requirement for the testing phase, we could have asked sites to decrease the rep count to a number which they like (based on community consensus in meta, if they would like to reduce the rep requirement). They can analyse the output with SE's help and then decide together what could be the way forward (decrease rep requirement further or bring back to original or stay as is for some more time).

Comment: We considered many different options, and the plan originally shared with mods several months ago was very different than this one. But the issue with any option other than 1 rep to vote is that it still gates voting behind a requirement to create well-received content (including suggest edits). Insisting content creation is necessary to validate if someone is capable of using a privilege, is a model we want to move away from. It may have gotten us here but that doesn't mean it's a good model.

Comment: The suggested edits queue on SO is nearly always full. Imagine if, instead of perpetually requiring all users with <2k rep to suggest edits because the edit privilege is locked to 2k rep, we instead granted the privilege to anyone who had at least 20 suggested edits and at least 19 of their 20 most recent suggestions were accepted. This could incentivise good edits, reduce the suggested edit queue size and maybe even earn a new suggested edit reviewer. If we stop granting edits at 2k by default, we could also reduce bad edits by high-rep users who don't actually know how to edit appropriately.

Comment: The two systems are very different but I use the edit privilege because it's been useful in showing users why the reputation-based system is flawed. We're preventing known-good editors from just doing what they do while we let someone who has a bunch of reputation but has never edited someone's post or had a suggested edit approved - edit freely with only the recent activity pages to invite any review from other users. Why? By using reputation to grant voting privileges, we're "trusting" users with 15 or 125 reputation and reducing the pressure to build tooling to review vote quality.

Comment: @Catija I'd love to see a system where people who upvote posts that get deleted as spam lose the ability to upvote, if that sort of thing is where those comments are hinting...

Comment: @Catija I appreciate your comments and I feel you briefly mentioned them [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387045/ "Why are we still using reputation to determine access to privileges anyway?"). I would have loved this project if we focused on giving edit access to good editors instead of high-rep users, instead of voting since voting is a complicated topic. Also, I concur with curiousdannii's [opinion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1314896) that people who don't use their votes properly, should be deprived of the privilege to vote.

Comment: They're not either-or, @RandomPerson - this is the first part of the project. While much more complex and harder to sell than the edit privilege changes I spoke of, it's one the product team has determined for various reasons is significantly more potentially valuable. I understand and agree with these reasons and have actually identified additional ways this change could really help sites. I have my own reservations and I accept that this is a big change with risks involved. Which is why we're working so hard to do it right. Once this is underway, expect to see me back at the edit privilege.

Comment: @Catija "Past me" would have been [very excited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252989/241211) about the "Good edit suggesters skip the queue" idea. Definitely more excited than about 1-rep votes. (Well, I think there is a decent case to be made for making the votes 'count' once you reach the rep thresholds, but I'll let other people describe that in their answers.)

Comment: @Catija Side note: I wanted to give you recognition for engaging in the comments. I disagree with the main proposal, but I admire the way you are talking with people even so. If I were in your place, I would not sound so even-tempered.

Answer (score 33):

#### A list of per-site meta discussion

Because I like lists <sup><sub>(except when chatgpt makes them)</sub></sup>.

From searching [`is:q [discussion] created:2023-09-19.. url:meta.stackexchange.com url:393127`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bdiscussion%5D+created%3A2023-09-19..+url%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+url%3A393127) on stackexchange.com. In order of [number of site questions](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions). Help is welcome with keeping this up to date.

**Please avoid "meta-meta-effect-ing" these meta discussions:** If you don't frequent said site, and you're not going to voice something specific to that community and its specific situation, leave their discussion be and let them have their talk (I'd even include leaving their voting be, but of course, I can't force you to do anything- only ask politely).

- Ask Ubuntu: [Should we not participate in the one-rep voting experiment?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20378/1624654)
- TeX - LaTeX: [Do we want to volunteer to test the lowered voting privilege?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10124/285516)
- Unix & Linux: [Should U&L participate in the "1 reputation voting" change?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7136/550426)
- Cross Validated: [Do we want to volunteer for the alpha test on lowering rep requirements for voting?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6578/373726)
- Arqade: [Should Arqade opt-in to the 1 reputation voting experiment?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16891/297372)
- Home Improvement: [No low rep voting, please!](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1765/159286)
- Graphic Design: [Should we volunteer to test 1-reputation voting?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3850/178122)
- Seasoned Advice: [Do we wish to be part of the 1-rep-voting test?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3823/102370)
- Arduino: [Should Arduino SE participate in the '1-rep voting' test?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2750/92500)
- Movies & TV: [Should Movies & TV SE participate in the 1 reputation voting experiment?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4953/98509)
- Code Golf: [Is code golf going to be opting into the voting reputation requirement test?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26023/115091)
- Pets: [We're considering helping with the 1 reputation voting trial](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2418/25617)
- Expatriates: [Do we want to participate in the 1 rep voting cap experiment?](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/472/25773)
- Retrocomputing: [Should we avoid the low rep voting experiment?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1221/26010)
- GenAI: [Do we want to volunteer to test the lowered voting privilege?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/189/33)

Answer (score 31):

### Stack Exchange is facing an existential crisis . . .

and it has been for some time.[^1] Back in 2014, I [proposed 4 attributes of a healthy Q&A site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271990/1438) based on a [2011 ACM paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20220626060907/https://bid.berkeley.edu/files/papers/mamykina-stackoverflow-chi2011.pdf):

- Number of active users,
- Percent of questions answered,
- Speed of answers, and
- Question views.

The first and the last directly impact the company's bottom line and the middle two matter to users. In [2016 gerrit noticed answer rates falling on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318719/why-are-answer-rates-dropping). Median time to first answer was also rising, but that's a lot harder to suss out from just using the site.

And then it became [*quite obvious*](https://jlericson.com/2023/06/02/strike_comentary.html) that you can get faster answers from ChatGPT than from asking on the internet. LLMs *always answer your question* and it can be argued that since they use a massive corpus, the number of people contributing to each answer dwarfs the competition. Shame that [the answers are simplistic and buggy](https://jlericson.com/2023/03/29/coding_ai.html), of course. Still, you can always ask again and maybe you'll get lucky.

It's important to see that ChatGPT was *the catalyst and not the cause*. Q&A sites can thrive if there's a reasonable chance the asker will get an answer before the problem is overtaken by events. Stack Overflow sucks up a lot of the attention, so let's look at Mathematics instead. Here's a graph of the average number of answers per question and the rate of questions that go unanswered after 30 days on that site:

[image: Answers per question and unanswered question rate for Mathematics]

This is not as scary as [Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/961239/unanswered-questions-by-year?window=30#graph), but it's nearing the point where getting an upvoted answer to a good question[^2] on Math is about the same as flipping a coin. Since [getting answers is the best encouragement for asking another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311504/what-can-we-do-to-encourage-or-discourage-a-second-question), this is a particularly detrimental to a Q&A site.[^3]

### There's nothing sacred about the voting model

I was a beta user on Stack Overflow. As such, I was invested in the project of creating a community for programmers. Thankfully [my argument for not having closed questions](https://web.archive.org/web/20081230154129/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/28833-get-rid-of-close-question-) did not win the day. But Joel and Jeff did take suggestions from the community. In order to get the site up and running, they also made decisions based on educated guesses of what would work rather than any sort of scientific experimentation or data analysis. Given the tremendous success of Stack Overflow it's easy to assume those choices were correct.

Still, even if those decisions were perfectly tuned (they weren't) a lot has happened in the past 15 years. It's important to verify that assumptions made in the past still hold. For instance, did you know there was a time when people worried that Stack Overflow might become ["brainless LOL-fest like Reddit or Digg"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)? Five years later someone commented (incorrectly) that people without reputation weren't able to ask questions at all. Pretty sure the network dodged the mindless fun bullet.[^4]

My point is that it would be foolish to *not question or test* the assumptions made early on.

### Letting new users vote probably won't make much difference

When the [feedback mechanism was introduced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing), it was a separate UI from the voting mechanism. At some point, the voting interface was repurposed for anonymous and low-reputation users to count as feedback. (Certainly by [May, 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179195/tooltip-for-anonymous-feedback-shows-click-again-to-undo-but-cant-really-be-u). Probably [late February of that year](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/245926/feedback-per-day-over-time?betathreshold=10#graph).) But it's never counted as an [actual vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285181/once-i-reach-15-reputation-will-my-old-votes-be-taken-into-account). Indeed, the action is recorded in an entirely separate table (`PostFeedback`) than regular votes (`Votes` on SEDE and `Post2Votes`, if I recall correctly, internally).

The proposed change moves the votes from registered users who can't vote because of reputation limits from the feedback table to the proper votes table. It also subjects these votes to all the restrictions of a real vote that (as far as I know) feedback is not subject to. For instance, votes will be rate limited and trigger voting fraud checks. So at least initially, there will be fewer votes than feedback events recorded. Over time the number might increase as users discover their votes now count.

So how many votes are we talking? For [the week of 2023-07-04 on Mathematics](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1787963/votes-per-day-over-time?betathreshold=10&opt.textResults=true), there were:

| Week of | Vote Type | Daily Average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-04 | UpMod | 1350.857142 |
| 2023-07-04 | DownMod | 267.571428 |
| 2023-07-04 | AcceptedByOriginator | 93.142857 |
| 2023-07-04 | ApproveEditSuggestion | 51.714285 |

So ~1,300 upvotes and ~270 downvotes a day. Here's the [post feedback for the same week](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/245926/feedback-per-day-over-time?betathreshold=10&opt.textResults=true):

| Week of | Vote Type | Daily Average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-04 | Anonymous DownMod | 1278.428571 |
| 2023-07-04 | Anonymous UpMod | 795.571428 |
| 2023-07-04 | Registered DownMod | 1.285714 |
| 2023-07-04 | Registered UpMod | 1.142857 |

Since we can differentiate between anonymous feedback (I believe tracked by IP internally) and low-reputation user feedback (tracked by user ID), we can see that visitors click the downvote arrow almost as many times in a day as voters upvote. People who find posts via Google, are much less inclined to select the up arrow in this sample. But the number of registered users who have attempted to vote before they have enough reputation is a tiny fraction of feedback. As in, I rounded off more when I summarized the vote averages just now. So if Mathematics volunteered for this experiment, most people wouldn't likely notice any difference. I haven't found any sites that show different results when I [use this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/245926/feedback-per-day-over-time?betathreshold=10#graph).

### No silver bullets and no poison pills

So why bother? I suspect the people who make strategic decisions at Stack Exchange Inc. view this as [low-hanging fruit](https://jlericson.com/2023/06/02/easy_answers.html) that will make a small difference with minimal work. But there's also a chance that this experiment will suggest other solutions to the problem. We've learned a lot more about how online communities operate since the privilege system was invented. Indeed, other community platforms learned from the Stack Exchange model to refine the concepts:

- [Codidact grants voting](https://meta.codidact.com/abilities/unrestricted) based on a quality threshold rather than a generalized reputation score.
- [Discourse begins trusting users](https://blog.discourse.org/2018/06/understanding-discourse-trust-levels/#trust-level-1-basic) after they've done a bit of reading.
- [TopAnswers](https://topanswers.xyz/meta?q=232) allows members of the community to vote (or "star") more posts based on the number of stars received.

These are very different ways of determining when a new user can be trusted. I have significant experience with Discourse's Trust Level system and it works incredibly well for [our community](https://talk.collegeconfidential.com/). While forums aren't the same as Q&A, requiring reading rather than posting seems a better way to bring people into a community. Removing the reputation gate to voting could allow better (or at least different) gates to be considered.

It's extremely unlikely this change will solve Stack Exchange problems. It's also unlikely the change will destroy Stack Exchange communities. As important as the privilege/reputation system is for those of us who deeply interested in online community platforms, the details don't really register for most new users. It's the accumulation of good incentives that create good communities.

---

[^1]: We tend to think of crises as fast moving: tsunami, stock market crash, terrorist attack, etc. If you are facing a slow-moving crisis, you will find it [much harder to raise the red flag](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/28201/did-ezekiel-fulfill-the-430-days-of-lying-on-his-left-right-side) since people don't usually feel the pain until it's too late to do anything about it. I'm obviously writing now because I believe there is still time to make changes that will keep Stack Exchange afloat.

[^2]: Note that the questions in the sample had a positive score and weren't closed or deleted in the 30 days after asking.

[^3]: Some might ask why encouraging a second question is valuable if we already have too many questions on the sites. I'd suggest that asking questions is a skill. I don't have proof, but I suspect the second question is almost always better than the first. I expect asking is also a path toward answering in the future.

[^4]: From experience I know someone reading this is thinking of a recent question that strayed into the mindless fun zone and would love to tell me about it. Don't bother. If you ask 100 people who have heard of Stack Exchange but haven't contributed whether fun questions are allowed, I'd be shocked if fewer then 99 said anything less than "hell no!"

Comment: I have theorized that many people currently don't vote as actively as they would because when they try to vote, they are told that their votes don't have "full effect". Like "what's the point if it doesn't count?". see also [Why do I forget to upvote useful questions and solutions?](/q/386212/997587). If that theory holds water, then your "_won't make much difference_" may not hold true as people gain "real" voting privileges.

Comment: @starball: That would be interesting to know! I don't have access to detailed voting data, but I suspect someone could get some idea of what would happen based on voting patterns after people get the voting privilege from 1) organic activity on the site or 2) the association bonus.

Comment: also, there's the fact that if you try to vote without an account, a popup appears that you need X reputation to vote up/down and makes no mention of anonymous feedback, and says: "_Join Stack Overflow to **start earning reputation and unlocking** new privileges like voting and commenting._". Which I think can lead to people not even trying to vote if they make an account until they get the vote privilege and get the privilege notification.

Comment: @starball While I may not have mentioned it in my post, we'd also be changing the copy in the register modal shown when someone who's not logged in attempts to vote.

Comment: I appreciate the work you've done to investigate this! I'm also really interested in understanding whether we'd see a big change in participation with this change. I do think it's interesting how many more anonymous downvotes Math gets than up! I noticed that a few months ago. Since I didn't look into which posts are getting downvoted (which would be really interesting!), I'm not sure whether those downvotes are "appropriate", so maybe I'll see if there are any specific posts seeing >5 downvotes from anon users and then see what the current score on those posts is.

Comment: It's worth saying that what @starball is questioning is why we're not taking the data directly as a prediction of the impact of this change and wanting to test it. I'd personally stop trying to vote if I knew I couldn't, so if that's the case for many users, a popup that their votes are counted now would hopefully lead them to start voting again.

Comment: "*we can see that visitors click the downvote arrow almost as many times in a day as voters upvote. People who find posts via Google, are much less inclined to select the up arrow in this sample.*" That's a very surprising statistic, but one that greatly assuages my concerns here.

Comment: @TylerH: To be clear, those sentences aren't about people who would be newly enfranchised. Registered users who don't have enough reputation to vote currently are still slightly more likely to downvote than upvote in this sample.  That's in sharp contrast to current voters who are far more likely to upvote than downvote. I suspect the downvote penalty plays some role, but it's possible people will change their voting habits when the vote count.

Comment: I did some poking around to see which posts are getting the most up/down feedback attempts. This is covered in the 10k tools but it doesn't actually show how much feedback was given that month. I looked at the posts with the 1000 most up and down on Math. There were some very odd extreme cases where questions received over 50 "downvotes" in the last month (7 posts), by the time the 1000 was rounded out, they were down to 5. "Upvotes" were lower, only 3 above 50 and down to 3 by 1000. This indicates to me that, for the most part, these vote attempts are spread around.

Comment: The skew between up and down on SO isn't so severe... but the gap has closed over the years since [I first started paying attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299930/voting-history-statistics-request/300575#300575). If memory serves, it tracks pretty closely with the vote patterns for very high reputation users, which suggests a natural tendency toward folks being more motivated to report disappointment than satisfaction, in keeping with patterns seen in other public review systems.

Comment: Sorry, @Michael, my query was for the top 1000, so when I got to 999 or 1000, whichever it shows last, only three up or five downvotes had been cast on those posts. My point being, while a small number of posts may see an outsized number of votes, on a site with over 3 million posts, only 1000 of the posts saw 3 or 5 anon/low rep votes in the last month. If we assume (possibly incorrectly) that the anon users are unlikely to join merely to vote on a single post, then the number of those vote attempts that become real votes would be lower.

Answer (score 27):

> Removing the reputation barrier to voting for all users is a change we
> feel will lead to more users being able to indicate post quality and
> usefulness, but we recognize that it will require a lot of care to
> ensure that we are **educating** voters about when to vote and encouraging
> them to follow acceptable voting practices while also preventing or
> removing votes that were cast inappropriately.

I can't say that SE has a good track record in educating users. I am not saying it is not possible, but so far most of the users in the network are poorly educated when it comes to how sites function, what is their purpose, which questions are on topic and which not. Most of the time users cannot even ask the question on the right site, so I am pretty skeptical that educating will work.

But main problem is not education, nor how you will do that. You are approaching this purely from the perspective of "good" users and problems which can arise when genuine users will use the sites where there is no reputation limit to voting.

Main problem are bad actors and the damage they could do to the sites, because there will be bad actors. And in quantities you will not be able to cater for.

Besides possible abuse with upvotes, there is also possible abuse with downvoting. I am less concerned with ability to downvote as this could be beneficial for question moderation on smaller sites, where you may have a number of otherwise experienced users that just don't have appropriate reputation on some sites in the network.

I am more concerned about removing reputation cost for downvoting answers which opens doors for revenge downvoting on answers. Now, this is not such an issue with answers that have plenty of upvotes, but on smaller sites where there are only handful of votes on answers this could be a real problem for answers that are of high quality but were being picked as a target. And you will not be able to catch and reverse all such downvotes.

At the end this might make people more reluctant to participate in moderation activities and this is what is your end goal.

Comment: What education needs to occur in this case? A question or answer is either useful to the user or it isn’t. We certainly didn’t “educate” any existing users who can vote any better.

Comment: @KevinB Probably that you are not allowed to abuse votes and what kind of voting patterns are considered as abuse.

Comment: How does earning 10 or 125 rep teach you that?

Comment: @KevinB It doesn't. But it implies that you have at least spent some time around the sites which cannot be said if you get voting privileges immediately. But educating is less of a problem comparing to what we have now. Bad actors are main issue when all safeguards are removed.

Answer (score 25):

If you only do this for engagement, why not show the upvotes from low-rep users only to themselves ([shadow-ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_banning)-like)?

Possibly with a tiny popup explaining that their upvotes won't be visible to others until they gain X reputation (whether this should retroactively apply past upvotes is up to discussion).

This precludes any curation quality issues.

Comment: this. or some similar form of it, such as showing the ratio of upmod to downmod votes. I've also been thinking of this. I don't see why not.

Answer (score 24):

Is SE prepared to make any commitment about the amount of developer time that will be allocated to building new tools to address the specific concerns raised by moderators (and users) about this change, based on feedback from the sites involved in the experiment?

This would influence my degree of enthusiasm for contributing to such a pilot.

Comment: The answer is no. You don't need an official answer (which you won't get) to see that.

Answer (score 24):

I think that such an experiment should come with *severe* reductions in the limits on voting for the users who gain voting privileges due to this (but not those who already have it). Maybe something like <strike>50</strike> 40 upvotes (or whatever the current *daily* limit is) for a whole week, and the daily limit lowered to a fifth or a seventh of that. If the experiment doesn't prove disastrous in the first week or so, then the limit can be slowly raised, say by another 50 votes per week or so until either the experiment ends or the existing voting limits are reached.

This will lower the monitoring burden on the staff conducting this experiment *and* lower the potential impact if the experiment goes haywire.

Comment: I was even thinking 1-3 votes per week.

Comment: On that note, how many votes can a regular user cast on a day?

Comment: @RandomPerson I went looking, and https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up says: "You can vote on posts 30 times per UTC day, plus 10 more times on questions only." It's the same on SO and AU, I don't know if any site has different limits.

Comment: From what I understand, we're not against an option like this as a next step. As part of discussion internally we considered this in a doc called "Scaling votes for low-rep users", which outlines a variety of options for awarding votes to users without relying on reputation. If you're familiar with way we award additional flags per day, that might give an idea of the sorts of things we were considering. For a test, we decided that a solution like this would add significant complexity to the voting rules and might not actually prevent misuse. It could also cause issues with data gathering.

Comment: When it comes to data, we want to know whether these new users would even use more than 3-5 votes per day and how their habits differ from privileged users. If we restrict their votes per day, we can't see if their behaviors are out of the norm and if that changes over time. And, no - I don't think we're putting the needs for complete data above the needs of the site. I'd argue that depending on how this was designed, it could actually make it more difficult for us to find and remove inappropriate votes.

Comment: Imagine if we create system restrictions that limit a user to a few votes per day - this could prevent or slow bursts of junk votes. It'd also make it significantly more difficult to detect the votes. A user dumping 30 votes in a day in a short period of time is easily flagged for investigation or handled by automations. A user casting 3-5, even if that's the upper limit, is more difficult to differentiate from normal use without there being something else concerning about the votes - such as them all going to a single user.

Comment: @Catija if the mechanism is too complicated to implement, then of course, nothing can be done, but assuming it can be, then your other two comments are addressed by scaling the limit up week by week (presumably you _are_ going to run this experiment for more than just one week?). The point is to "flatten the curve" a bit, not to _stop_ abuse - voting limits have never stopped abuse, as you well know. See how new users do with a limit of normal-use-level, then scale it up and see how they do with more. Wouldn't that actually give you more data on user behaviour?

Comment: It's not too complicated to implement - it's overly complicated to explain to users during a test why they only have 5 votes one week but have 10 votes next week and 15 the following. I can't see how slowly scaling votes for all users simultaneously as the test progresses would be useful. I don't have any data at hand but my understanding is that the average user doesn't vote 40 times per week. I'd be surprised if they voted more than 0-2 times per week, so I'm actually even more confused at this point.

Comment: @Catija come now, that's infantilizing. I think people can understand easily enough the concept of being allowed to do more the longer you have been using a system. Or are you trusting people to understand voting, while expecting them to be unable to understand that?

Comment: Yes, more rate limiting would allow the persistent ones to vote. They just have to wait longer (they are persistent, so it will not be a problem).

Comment: I think I'm not understanding what you're saying, then or my mental image is far more complex than yours. If I was an occasional user of a site and I came one day and had a notice that I could vote but only 10 times, I'd say "cool - 10 seems like a lot". If I came back the next week and got a similar message but it's now 20 - well... I only used four but, OK. Maybe I'll need them some day. Week three, new notice, 30 votes.... at some point I'm going to get annoyed by the notifications or confused about why it's changing constantly.

Comment: @Catija "Hey new user! We're trialling out allowing all users to vote on Stack Overflow! Because it's a trial, the number of votes you are allowed each week might change, as we try to figure out usage patterns. *blah blah blah*"

Comment: Telling people so overtly about the test plan is not something we're planning to do. If you tell them it's a trial it risks them using votes differently than they might normally. Our current designs only tell users they have the ability, nothing about the test. We won't conceal it - meta posts may be visible but that's not the same at all.

Comment: @Catija I have no idea what your designs look like, post them and then I can think of better suggestions, and even if I can't, other users definitely will. But going with the limited information you're giving me, I guess you have the limit in some sort of dismissible notice? Don't mention the limit after the first time. When they do hit the limit, just let them know they'll be "getting *even more* votes next week, be sure to come back!" And as you say, normal users don't vote that much. So only a few unusual ones will be seeing that, right?

Comment: If a measly 125 rep is to be considered too high a barrier, then I would be **much** happier with giving low-rep users a **much** smaller number of votes per day than those with (currently) full voting privileges.  Like maybe 1 upvote (and no downvotes) per day.

Comment: @JohnBollinger My earlier comments here specifically say that's something we've considered for future implementation but if the average (or even majority) of low rep user only votes 1-2 times per day anyway, the limit is kinda unneeded for the most part. We won't know what limit makes sense unless we get true data of how many times per day users will vote if given the chance. We know that 40 is almost never needed. For active users, even 5 is uncommon, based on my memory but it's been known to fail from time to time.

Answer (score 22):

I want to respond to [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393127/if-more-users-could-vote-would-they-engage-more-testing-1-reputation-voting-on?cb=1#comment1314844_393138), but I feel the response is more generally applicable.

> Insisting content creation is necessary to validate if someone is capable of using a privilege, is a model we want to move away from. It may have gotten us here but that doesn't mean it's a good model.

I actually roughly agree: the ability (and desire) to moderate is distinct from the ability to write good content, and it might not be the best idea to have content creation be the (only) criterion for moderation, as is currently the case.

**However**, what you're proposing here is to completely remove the criterion and not replacing it by anything.

So the question this experiment tries to answer is: "is this criterion better or worse than no criterion". I doubt that it's worse (at least on sites that are already struggling with quality control... which is most sites I've used). Creating *some* good content (or at least positively-received content) seems unlikely to be a net-negative criterion for being able to judge what good content looks like, even if it isn't a *good* criterion.

The better question to try to answer is: "is this criterion better or worse than some other criterion". This experiment would only give us information about that if our current criterion is actively harmful, which would make it worse than any criterion that provides any benefit whatsoever. But if it provides some benefit (however small), this wouldn't tell us how it compares to other possible criteria.

A better criterion might be to somehow ["educate users on what to upvote, what to downvote and what not to upvote or downvote"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393135/229562) (and possibly also including a test to make sure they actually read any of that and understand it).

---

I suppose we might also have different priorities when it comes to judging what's "good". You seem to be largely/primarily motivated by the "hope to spur participation and engagement", whereas I care more about retaining and improving quality, even if that means limiting participation.

On that note, you seem (for a long time now) to be moving away from the model of a limited number of users creating a Q&A to be passively used by a large number of users, and moving more towards trying to maximise the number and degree of engagement of active participants. There are already many, many sites focusing on the latter, but quite few focusing on the former.

I suppose the question is also then how you'd judge the results. If there's a slight decrease in quality, but there are more votes, would that be considered a success?

As a side note: the score of a post could skew people's perspective on the quality of that post. It's not inconceivable that people think quality improved simply as a result of new users upvoting things more and there thus being fewer negatively-scored posts. I'm not sure it's even possible to avoid that, without making people aware of their potential bias ahead of time (but that creates other problems).

Comment: I would suggest that the ability to ask good questions and write good answers does correlate pretty well with being able to identify good questions and good answers. It may not be causation, but it sure is better than nothing.

Comment: @JonCuster I think the basic exposure to and familiarity with how things work is probably most important, after which reputation may become more arbitrary. ... but that basic exposure is exactly what they're proposing be removed.

Comment: Forgive the quibble but we're not proposing to "remove the criterion" and I find that framing is unfair. We're proposing to **test** removing the criterion on sites that *volunteer* for it. That test plan includes a commitment to actively monitor the sites during the test and seek out indications of users voting in ways outside current community norms so that they can be investigated and determined if they are problematic and would need to be addressed. We have even stated that the test metrics are not final because we want the sites participating to help us define them.

Comment: We additionally outline that we will (with the sites) identify a rollback plan should the voting behaviors lead to issues we can't quickly address by adding to existing tools and automations or the volume of issues becomes too much for the moderators or site to handle. Creating additional criteria when we don't even know for sure that they're needed could lead to us simply replacing existing bad barriers with new ones. Many of the ideas that have been floated about additional criteria I've outright said that we've either considered or would consider *if we see a need for them*.

Comment: Votes by definition are the backbone of how this platform indicates quality. If there's a drop in the percentage and absolute number of votes and voters per day (which is seen on many sites), keeping current barriers to voting is going to eventually cause quality indicators to be non-existent. When we say we want to spur participation and engagement *through voting* rather than through projects like Jobs or Documentation, we're trying to invest in and increase quality signal on these sites rather than pulling engagement off to non-core Q&A work.

Comment: Along with this drop in voting, I'm pretty sure there's fewer users who write more than one answer in some period of time along with fewer curators, editors, flaggers, even people willing to be moderators. [Here's a comment on this page of what not earning votes on good content can do to user motivation.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393127/if-more-users-could-vote-would-they-engage-more-testing-1-reputation-voting-on?noredirect=1#comment1314938_393146) It's not about moving away from the library concept that relies on a a small group creating a big resource.

Comment: But at some point you have to ask "is that small group too small?" and start looking into why that is the case. We don't know that voting is a panacea. It probably isn't. But if we can do it carefully, thoughtfully in a data-driven way, it might start moving the needle back towards having more quality signal and more incentives for new content creators who might become the next million-rep user. We want to let people show us they *can* vote well and figure out where to give them a nudge if it's needed rather than assuming they won't.

Comment: @Catija If long-term users participate less, and you replace them with new users who don't know what's going on, or who don't really care about the quality of the site, that'll probably push long-term users further away. On 2 of my most frequented sites I just stopped participating altogether because too many others don't seem to care about quality, or they're actively and loudly opposed to having pretty much any quality standards (not that those users were necessarily new). Whether you "see a need" for additional criteria depends to a significant degree on what you want the site to be. ...

Comment: @Catija If you want a high-quality Q&A, I don't see that happening without some guidance or barrier of entry for new voters. Otherwise the site will shift towards *what people like* instead of what meets the guidelines and what you've established is a good fit for a Q&A (and detecting that could be quite hard). Bad votes are worse than fewer votes. But "high-quality Q&A" doesn't seem like it's been a goal for probably the last decade or so (even if something in line with that pops up every once in a while).

Comment: @Catija There are drops in participation for reasons that have been detailed on Meta. I don't think "too few voters" ranks in like the top 10 reasons, so this seems to be less about bringing those people back and more about just pumping some life back into the site. How many users are too few? I expect on Stack Overflow, you can cut the users down to 10%, or even 1%, and that would only improve things. There seems to be some odd combination of too many question askers, so many duplicate and unanswered questions, but also too many answerers, so frequently duplicate answers per question.

Comment: @Catija More voters doesn't seem like it would improve things there. But then you aren't proposing this for Stack Overflow (yet). Maybe some smaller sites are desperately in need of more voters, I wouldn't know. I suspect more would struggle with having too few people asking or answering questions, or too few moderating (voting is a small part of that, but more for downvoting than upvoting, and in my experience, new users are much more likely to upvote things, even bad things, which certainly doesn't help).

Answer (score 21):

I was going to post this as a comment, but I decided to post as an answer instead to try to get more visibility to this issue.
Forgive me if others already mentioned this and/or if I am missing something obvious.

[Isn't this "test" virtually the same thing that was attempted on GenAI and caused an incredible amount of backslash??](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391527/se-is-breaking-the-reputation-privilege-system)

What would be different this time? What made the company believe that something like a proposal that already caused a lot of negative feedback in the past (even if it was later revealed to be a **partial** misunderstanding due to poor wording) would be received positively now? Didn't the users already point out all the mess this would cause back then?

To put this into context:

> I am very opposed to setting a 1 rep threshold for up and down voting because these have an implication across the network. Unless you plan to exclude GenAI from granting the linked account reputation bonus, this could negatively impact other sites by granting users who have no or limited understanding of the system or the network with additional powers.
> [Thomas Owens, GenAI](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/72/61)

> One major concern that I (and likely others) share is that this may (and likely will) lead to voting rings and (rule breaking) sockpuppet accounts. As an added measure to prevent the effects of that spilling over to other sites, can that bonus be disabled, please?
> [cocomac, this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393129/171199)

I'll leave finding the other overlapping answers as an exercise for the reader.

If I just read this post without any further context I am left asking myself if anyone in the company read that discussion again before posting this? It got "shot down" when we were talking about a ***single***  and ***new*** site, and now we are back at arguing if it should be made for multiple existing sites at the same time?

I would also wonder why wasn't the association bonus - something users already warned you about - mentioned by design this time, and if we really needed cocomac to mention it again before someone remembered to address it here.

But then when actively asked about that Catija mentioned that:

> We've had several discussions both with Mods and internally about the Association Bonus and we're definitely thinking about it. Based on my last conversation about it, we see several options for this and have documentation of those options.

Based on this, and further comments below it appears that the issue **was** internally mentioned. But then why did you choose to not include it in the summary when you already knew how important it was for some users? That line should have been posted from the start, and preceded by a "We remember your concerns when a similar test was proposed for GenAI so we are currently discussing a solution so that said problem can be circumvented".

Again, I get your attempts to make things short and easier to read but... you really have to work on how you communicate things and what to keep/drop.

Comment: "_Forgive me is others already mentioned this_" just two comments from my ctrl+f in devtools. no answer posts before yours- at least- none that link to that MSE post. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393127/if-more-users-could-vote-would-they-engage-more-testing-1-reputation-voting-on/393191#comment1314714_393127, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393127/if-more-users-could-vote-would-they-engage-more-testing-1-reputation-voting-on/393191#comment1314719_393135

Comment: I mean, I think it’s silly to assume they weren’t aware of all of this given their past comments on these very things in the past 8 months.

Comment: This project actually predates the GenAI site by quite a lot. Despite statements I've seen made in some places, the GenAI site was not an alternate way to test this project. They are not related at all and different CMs are involved. These two projects are different in several key ways. This is *only* about reputation to vote, involves significant amount of data gathering and support by staff during the test to enhance tools and automations based on that data throughout the test.

Comment: That proposal was about reducing *all* privileges to mimic private beta levels on a brand new site. It was posed to the community directly with no indications of it being a "test" or having any product support to address voting issues. While many of the concerns related to voting privileges directly, the huge differences that do exist in the projects would not lead me to say they're "virtually identical" unless maybe I was only looking at the titles of the questions.

Comment: Your assertion about the Association Bonus being ignored or forgotten is incorrect. The question states that it was drafted to be more on the short side - it's still four pages long vs the 8-9 of the Mod Team post. That's not to hide things, it's because if I had included everything that I knew people were going to ask about, it would be three times longer than it is now and I don't think that's digestible. As such, I made an intentional decision to respond to direct questions/concerns about specific things as they came in. I stand by that choice.

Comment: @Catija See the last see the last passage in the post. I didn't meant anyone wanted to "hide" things. I am pointing out it looks like it was a very bad idea to not include a central point of the previous similar discussion (especially if the company ***did*** do its "homework" internally and further discussed it) because the obvious outcome is that people will look at the post, see it is again about the same basic idea, see that their concerns weren't addressed and once again think your left hand doesn't know what the right one is doing.

Comment: @Catija it is not a "work" issue - it is a communication one. The summary forgot to include things that IMHO should have been at the core of a similar communication, with the outcome of making the company again ***look*** like it does not care for feedback. And in this case this is not true by your own claim, so allow me to say it is quite a pity.

Comment: @Catija Anyway I have edited the post based on the *new* information you disclosed so that it should be more evident that this is a critic to the way the company communicates and not on the actual actions (that said, I will also add that *imho* this idea is still very useless if not actively bad) . As for the "similar only in title", I'll agree to disagree. Context may be different but the outcome and more importantly the effect - again **imho** - did greatly overlap, especially in relation to the association bonus issue.

Answer (score 19):

This experiment identifies a discrepancy between "outcomes that benefit StackOverflow Inc." and "outcomes that benefit StackExchange Users", in a way that is going to make it hard for mods to trust any results of the site test.

Let me explain.

This question is posited as "would lowering voting thresholds increase *engagement*".  But engagement, as in "users spending more time on the site", is not what most SEs need.  Most of the SEs I participate in need *more quality questions and answers*.

So from a perspective of mods and other users of SE, what we'll want to know is "does being able to vote sooner result in users posting their first question/answer sooner, and how good are those questions/answers?"  There is absolutely no reason to believe that it will, given that they haven't posted already, but I could be pleasantly surprised.

There are four possible outcomes for this test:

1. No change in behavior
2. Low-rep users do lots of voting but don't post
3. Low-rep users post more, but the posts are low-quality
4. Low-rep users post more, and the posts are high-quality

Of the above, outcomes 2 and 3 can be actually harmful to many or most SE sites' usability; they are certainly not clearly "successful" outcomes.

In contrast to this experiment, I'd be interested in one where we lowered the threshold required to comment.  I can see a much more direct line from commenting to answering/asking than from voting to posting.

Another experiment that we could try would be to eliminate the "canonical questions rule", which is one of the major things driving the decline in user posting activity.  As an SE ages, it gets harder and harder to ask an actually "new" question, so why bother?

Comment: "_I'd be interested in one where we lowered the threshold required to comment_" I would not. Not until the site UI does a good job of actually making people read [`/help/privileges/comment`](/help/privileges/comment). why more comments? what value does that add? how does it serve the overarching mission in line with the overarching methodology? I could spend multiple eternities cleaning up comments that should not have been posted and never be done.

Comment: I agree that the site UI should do a better job EVERYWHERE of linking new users to docs on how to use the site.  The number of times I've linked "What to Ask" doesn't bear counting.

Comment: While I agree that some sites do need more Q&A activity, I think it's not universally the case or the only thing the site needs. On SO in particular they have so many duplicates asked that very few of the daily questions are novel and many others are low quality. But you seem aware of that considering your last paragraph. Your four possible outcomes don't consider secondary impacts. Someone who doesn't get votes on the content they create may disengage because it's not worth their time. How many people have left the communities because of that?

Comment: Catija: sounds like you're on your way to a robust set of metrics to figure out whether this worked or not; as long as you measure more detailed activity than "spending more time on the site" I'm happy.  Looking at some of the comments I've realized that I mostly participate in SEs where there are still plenty of votes (and existing voting behavior already has issues), but Q&A activity has fallen.  I'd assumed that this was common, but maybe it's just a subset of SE.

Comment: What I wanted to stress it that turning into reddit, where there are tons of votes but very little other user behavior, is not a successful outcome.

Comment: eh, giving people things they can actually do that doesn't require the stress of creating content can certainly ease people into the Q&A "ecosystem" and make them more likely to engage in asking/answering later.

Comment: I didn't say anything about spending time on the site - anywhere on this post. "Engagement" is not equivalent to "views" - it's actually interacting with the site rather than just consuming it. I'm willing to allow that in your opinion, *only* voting might as well not be considered more engagement than passive consumption. That may be true but (as @KevinB just stated) it can be a gateway. You may have experienced the feeling a bit yourself when you wanted to downvote this question - you couldn't vote and you commented on the irony of wanting to downvote and being unable to - on this question.

Comment: You're a veteran user of the network and meta (though not MSE). As such, it doesn't surprise me that you would be willing to answer the question to gain the few points you need (downvotes on MSE actually only require 100 rep as it is) to earn the privilege. If you'd not written a post before - or your attempts to post had been met with downvotes or even *no* votes - can you see that it might leave you feeling even more frustrated to the point that you felt so left out you would just wash your hands of the site entirely? Maybe not the first time - but what if it happened every time?

Comment: Somehow in this whole conversation I've fallen into a sort of trap - in focusing on talking about 1 rep users *unwilling* to create content, I've forgotten all of the ones who have. While many of those may have been downvoted, it's also possible someone could have 1 rep because their attempts to contribute got no votes.... and if that's because a site has depressed voting, it's kinda a vicious cycle. People create good content, get no votes, can't earn the privilege to vote, and then fewer people vote. Communities aren't static. Members do leave, so without voting, the new members can't come.

Comment: We've both been active on Cooking - it's a great site and I love the people I know from there. Some of the best lessons about how to help askers do better and being willing to actually do the work to save questions that show a spark of value came from that site. It's something I treasure about it. So when you say that SA has "plenty of votes", it confuses me. In the past month, only 15 users have voted more than 10 times. Of the open questions from the most recent 50, 18 have a score of 0,  17 have a score between 1-3, 4 between 4-9 and 4 a score 10+. Five were hot network questions.

Comment: Now, I'm not actually reading the questions to see if they deserve votes or checking vote splits to see if those 0 scores are actually 0 votes, but even if they aren't, to a visitor, having 18/43 of the questions from the last 20 days with a score of zero could lead them questioning whether their question would get any attention. You've probably seen the questions and answers - why do you vote (or not vote)? Personally, I usually forget unless I'm really amazed by the post making my brain explode with an incredible answer. Hopefully most people aren't like that.

Comment: Its probably worth splitting out the proposal on canonicals, since that is a highly controversial proposal that really gets to the core of what stackexchange's goals are. Do we want more questions if they go over the same ground? I'm not saying there isn't room for refinement there, especially on how we deal with new material with respect to canonicals, but just saying remove it isn't likely to go down well and will distract from the rest of this answer.

Comment: Catija: looking over the most recently asked questions on SA, the 0 votes are almost all intentional.  If you look at the 0 vote questions, you see that they're mostly questions on the verge of being closed (lack of clarity, missing details, etc.).  They're zeros because they should be zeros.  Personally, if I read a question that's reasonably well-written, I upvote it unless it already has a bunch of upvotes.

Comment: You're correct that the number of upvotes per question is small.  That's because the number of active users in SA has fallen by at least 70% from 4 years ago.  I don't think voting rights are the main reason for that.  Instead, it's canonical answers, Google, first-to-post, absolute seniority, and the simple fact that it's hard to form a social community on a site where there aren't really places to socialize.  The decline of the SE platform was inherent in its design; it simply doesn't give people good reasons to stick around.  I don't believe that voting will change that.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Yet, as you mentioned from the problem of the discrepancy between goals. If question numbers are going down because of canonical answers, the received wisdom is that from the point of view of the users, that is a success, not a failure. Because it means people are able to find the answer to their question, without needing have someone go through the process of answering it. Now, there are issues with canonicals drifting, but it being harder and harder to ask a new question isn't in itself seen as a problem by the technical site userbases.

Comment: The goal is not to have people post their questions, its to get their question answered, and a question that is answered without them posting anything is a massive win.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  And you can see how that's "steadily decreasing user activity by design", right?

Comment: @FuzzyChef In which case, signed in user activity is the wrong metric. We need a metric that measures users satisfaction in actually solving problems, not just addicting them to the supply of fish that rapidly burns out answerers.

Comment: Its not even like user activity is what matters to the buisness model. The core metrics from a profit perspective are page ad views and page ad clicks. And we aren't a social media sight where people only see those ads if they enguage. The drive by answer viewers who have there problem solved by existing questions, at least from the anecdotal stats I see, are the vast majority of the page ad views.

Comment: Questions asked is a third level removed in the chain. Questions Asked -> Answers Generated -> Passive Views -> Ad money. Maybe rather than focusing on more questions, we should be looking at how to optimize the existing question base, by generating answers to existing questions that are more useful for more views.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why answering, "I left my food on the counter for 8 hours, is it still safe to eat?" thousands of times is a good thing. Is that what you're arguing for? I've been in Discord servers where they just answer every question as it's asked for months before finally getting tired of it and creating a FAQ channel with only answers to the most common questions. Even in highly-social spaces, canonicals are necessary because people stop wanting to answer every single person who asks. They take up all the energy and cause people to quit.

Comment: SA has been an extremely social space in the past. Along with M&TV and ELL, it's the place I've spent the most hours in chat and I've actually met - in person - two of the people I know from SA. I totally accept that people on many sites want more ways to be social but that doesn't mean they don't exist. I don't know your preferences but if Chat isn't your thing, that doesn't mean there's no social options. I'm here because of the social options that exist on the platform. I wouldn't have stayed without the people I met and came to know and care about.

Comment: Catija: as someone who's been in open source for 25 years and has run forums since the BBS days, I have a lot to say about how the path from BBS --> SE has been reductive and resulted in declining socialization.  BUT, that feels pretty far off topic from this comment thread.  If SE provided us a place to discuss such things, we could discuss it, but it doesn't, and that's the essence of the trend.

Answer (score 19):

You folks (owners and operators of StackExchange and StackOverflow) seem to have confused the Stack sites with a social network.  That's wrong.  It's as wrong as those who confuse the Stack sites with forums.

The Stack sites are about knowledge, not about random interactions with people.  Voting on the Stack sites is not about social interaction.  It is about evaluating content.

Given that, increasing user activity just to have more activity is pointless.

Would you suggest that Wikipedia encourage edits to articles just to have more activity?  I'd hope not. On Wikipedia, you want directed activity to improve the content - not random edits just to generate activity.

Just so with the Stack sites.  You want directed activity to improve the content and generate new content.

Because you are looking at the Stack sites as something they are not, you are also looking at the wrong metrics.

This is the the question you should be asking:

> How many people per day are finding the information they need on the Stack sites?

Follow that up with:

> Has the number of successful searches increased or decreased over the years?

From the [publicly available data,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387302/658721) it is clear that activity is dropping.

Other data may show an entirely different picture, but only the company behind the Stack sites can view that data - that's number of page views per day, number of pages views by new and returning people, and time spent on page.

That information would tell you if the Stack sites are still providing information to people.

---

For nearly any subject, there's a certain basic level of information that you need to be able to work in that area.  Once you've covered the basics, it becomes far more difficult to find good (general) questions and good (general) answers - you start getting into details and questions specific to a particular usage.  Those more specific questions will attract fewer votes and fewer answers (also with fewer votes.)  They require more experience to understand and more experience to answer - and most people capable of understanding and writing such detail questions on a particular subject will be capable of answering their own questions without ever asking anyone for help.

Once you've gotten a huge base of basic questions, activity (creation of new content) will slow down.

When activity slows down, you need to take a good look at your content and the viewing patterns and see whether people are simply finding the information they need (loads of new people viewing existing content for extended periods or people returning with long view times) or if your site has become irrelevant (no new people visiting or short, one-time visits with no returns.)

Activity (new questions/answers, voting) are certainly down - the linked SEDE queries clearly show dropping numbers of new questions and answers for years.  The information needed to see if Stack is still relevant is, however, not available through SEDE.  The company needs to look at that, preferably while making the numbers and the analysis public.

- Looking at the activity alone is not sufficient.
- Looking at the Stack sites as you would a social network is wrong.
- Look at details relevant to a knowledge repository (what the Stack system is supposed to be) to see if the Stack sites are still relevant before making random changes to what may be the wrong parameters.

---

Views per day is what drives your advertising revenue.  If I suddenly started using up my voting quota every day, it wouldn't do your revenue any good - I'm already there every day, viewing dozens if not hundreds of questions and answers along with the ads.

Increased activity does not equate to more ad views and ad revenue - for that you need more viewers.

Are there sufficient viewers on the Stack system?

I don't know, but I seriously hope that the Stack owners can find out.

---

Out of curiousity, I checked the "Impact" rating on my Electrical Engineering stack page.

It says I've "reached" 2.3 million people.  The pop-up says that's an estimate of the number of times my answers have been read based on how often the questions I have answered have been read.

I have 67,838 reputation points on that site. To simplify the math, assume each point came from an upvote (10 points.)  That's that 6783 people who have voted on my answers.  That means that only one person in 339 bothers to vote.  It also means that the real activity (people reading existing questions and answers) on the site is over 300 times more than just the voting activity suggests.

This is, of course, just a quick look at a single data point.

I'd suggest that the folks operating the Stack system could look at aggregate numbers and come up with a better number for how many times existing questions and answers are read as opposed to how often people "interact" with the system - and I'd bet that the number of passive readers will **drastically** outnumber the "interactions" that the Stack operators are looking at.

The trend of the passive readers is what they need to be looking at - that's where the "eyeballs" for the ad revenue come from.

---

For a further comparison, I have a blog with a really simple voting system - users are not required to log in to vote on posts.

Since May of this year, there have been less than 100 votes (positive and negative.)  That's in comparison to over 13000 page views.

That's a ratio of 130 views to 1 interaction - and that's where interactions are truly no effort for the readers.

As I mentioned in an [answer on the Writing stack,](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/53366/is-an-audience-really-required-to-develop-writing/53370#53370) people come looking for information - they are doing something and need information.  They find it on my blog (or on some Stack) and return to what they were doing.  They are concentrating on the task and are **not interested in the least** in "interacting."  They have something to do, and they want (or need) to get back to it.  I know this because I do it myself - need some obscure bit of info, search, find, return to task.

You need to look at what all those "passive" consumers are doing and stop concentrating on interaction.

Answer (score 18):

> ...the core concept behind all of them is to prevent misuse and protect the perceived value of the content on the sites...

Let me focus on the core concept. Misuse is surely a concern for voting but another maybe underrated concern should be experience. Inexperienced voters could destroy the perceived value of the content on the sites by various actions including:

- voting based on already existing votes or reputation of a content creator instead of voting based on content
- voting based on a wrongful or missing understanding of the content and the context
- voting based on sympathy with the contributors situation
- voting not based on anything substantial (random noise)

and while this is true for all kind of votes, it may occur on a much larger scale with low reputation users. It doesn't require bad intent, so it doesn't represent an abuse, but still more votes of lower quality could actually be harmful instead of beneficial for the platform.

I therefore urge you to develop a success metric that directly measures how positive or negative contributions of increased amounts of votes impact the quality of the voting as best as possible.

And I advise to also try different thresholds and not simply lowering it to 1 in order to test if there maybe is an optimum somewhere. I think there might be.

Finally it doesn't necessarily need to be tied to reputation, maybe there are other ways to define how much weight a vote should have. And I think it's not so trivial to come up with a really useful metric for estimating the direct impact of this change on the quality of voting. In general, we need the right kind of people to vote on the right kind of content in order to maximize the value of voting,  I think. Not sure how that can be achieved.

Comment: sympathy voting is something I suspect I see a lot on reddit with poorly asked questions. I'd much rather have people vote on stack exchange (like they generally should on stack exchange) be based on usefulness: "this question was useful because it was searchable when I had the same problem" / "this answer is useful because it helped me with the problem I had when I searched and found this Q&A".

Comment: Said success metric should be defined and published to meta before going ahead with the test. _Not after_.

Comment: We don't have a success metric currently to share - because we want to understand what success would look like to the sites that are volunteering rather than making one up ourselves. All of your other suggestions I've responded to in other places, I think. The point of the test is to see what the bare impact of this is and determine how best to address any issues that show up. If the primary outcome is socks and voting rings, we'll work on that. If we see a lot of people voting out of alignment with existing voters, we'll work on that... or both... or whatever else.

Comment: @Catija If you don't have a metric yet then I wanted to nudge you towards one with this answer. You won't know what success looks like otherwise. Specifically any conclusion like more votes are always better should be avoided. And typically it's best practice to define success goals before beginning an experiment. That avoids a lot of biases that might otherwise come into play later. This answer is simply what I think is the important thing here.

Comment: Several metrics have already been identified as thing that will be tracked and looked at, what i think is missing is statements on how the company expects these changes to play out and which metrics would be useful for proving or disproving those theories. Not necessarily stating "if it doesn't reach X bar it will be reverted", but rather "We expect to see an increase in voting that loosely aligns with existing voting trends and if we instead see trends that are different, we'll investigate why they're different."

Comment: Creating a hard line "if it doesn't do X, we'll revert" is a rather poor position to put yourself in when it's possible it could fail to do X but still succeed in another useful way that wasn't predicted.

Comment: @KevinB has sort of written my response for me here. The question and comment each indicate that we want to write metrics with the communities involved to ensure we're looking for harmful outcomes that the sites predict. Even if you think the company wants to set a metric like "more votes are always better" (which we don't, to be absolutely clear), do you imagine the communities involved would?

Comment: @Catija It's totally fine if the communities define the metric before the experiment starts. And while nobody has said that, more votes are always better seemed to me a bit like the undertone in this Q&A. I wanted to point out that a useful metric would also allow more votes to be worse sometimes. That as a minimal requirement. Otherwise you know how these experiments end. Somebody will write a conclusion and in that conclusion some metric will be chosen to justify further steps even if that choice might be biased. That's why one should do it before.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution I think the answers have assumed that is the position of the company. It is incorrect and the question specifically states that we're planning to compare voting between new voters and existing ones to see if there are differences. If we only cared about more votes, why would we assess whether the votes are aligned with community norms?

Comment: @Catija I just wrote what I think is best practice in this case. Maybe my concern will turn out to be completely unjustified. Who knows. Afterwards I will know better.

Answer (score 17):

> Setting guidance before the test that will help us identify cases where rolling back the changes or making other adjustments are necessary."

1. so rolling things back (after the experiment ends) will be a possibility?
2. is it just rolling back the votes, or also the knock-on effects of people using privileges they gained as a result of the change, such as commenting (imagine all the noise), doing reviews, making edits without review, etc.?
3. if it's possible, what's the rationale for rolling back not being a given (instead of a decision point), given that this is just an experiment?

Comment: Our *plan* is to only roll back if we meet the guidance for doing so or if unexpected negative outcomes cause us to determine that rolling back is the best course of action. This can happen at any point during the test, not only after the test period has elapsed. If we can make adjustments or improvements to tools instead of rolling back, that's an alternative we will consider. We'd prefer finding ways to address issues rather than having to stop the test entirely but, in particular, if addressing issues would take too long, we will revert the change.

Comment: The main change of a rollback would be resetting the privilege levels for up- and downvoting to their current levels (15 and 125) to prevent additional voting. In my understanding, we likely wouldn't remove *all* low-reputation votes cast during the test by default. Our general expectation is that most votes cast would be within site expectations so we'd focus on invalidating votes known to be problematic. That doesn't mean we wouldn't ever decide to remove all votes but doing so would likely be quite complex as votes give rep and rep gives voting... someone can earn the privilege mid-test.

Comment: The main line of reasoning for not rolling back at the end of the test period is because we're going to be reviewing data throughout the process. If there's no overt negative impact we recognize during the test, it's unclear that rolling back while reviewing additional data is necessary. This also risks the impacted low-rep users being confused by the loss of the voting privilege they just gained... which might be reinstated again a short time later. This is a change from other tests we've run in the past but I think it makes sense in this situation.

Comment: @Catija the way you describe the roll-back plan here reads to me as if SE has already decided to implement this plan come hell or high-water, but is 'whitewashing' it by announcing it as an experiment to make it look as though you're acting in good faith. The lack of a defined period of time over which this 'experiment' will run further reinforces this impression for me. In my mind, an experiment should run for some defined period of time while you gather data. After the experiment ends you make a decision - using the data you gathered - whether to implement the thing you experimented with.

Comment: If only "unexpected negative outcomes" might lead to a roll-back of this 'experiment', could you clarify what some *expected* negative outcomes might be, and why these negative outcomes would be acceptable and not real to a roll-back of the 'experiment'?

Comment: @brhans presumably that'd mean an unmitigable amount of fraud being caused by it, since that is the primary concern for the outcome of this change. Given it's going to roll out to select sites, not network-wide, during the experiment we should get a fairly effective view from that as far as what additional tools are necessary to mitigate any increase in fraud before it rolls out to larger sites. Put another way, a negative outcome isn't necessarily the end of the experiment, rather, it's an opportunity to mitigate those problems and continue.

Comment: @brhans I don't think that's quite correct. As my comments say, the goal is to avoid granting, removing and re-granting privileges in a short period of time. There is the potential that we'll look at the data after the test period and determine that it's causing more harm than good and roll it back at that point. I don't mention that, so it's understandable why you'd interpret it that way. The other thing worth keeping in mind is that this sort of change may not be immediately understandable. Removing the test after only a month could cause us to overlook much.

Comment: There could be positive or negative outcomes we'll only see in six months or a year because this change leads to a gradual shift. So, again, rolling back and considering the test "done" after only a month would negatively impact the long-term understanding of the change. When it comes to negative outcomes, we're thinking of huge increases in moderator flags or need to handle content, or the community indicating that they can't delete content that they should be able to due to an influx in upvotes on good content... or good content being downvoted when it shouldn't.

Comment: But in many of these cases, we'll want to investigate where these votes are coming from to better understand the motivation for these votes. Other possible outcomes are ones we see throughout this discussion - unexpected numbers of socks being created to target votes at specific accounts (up or down). It can seem somewhat hand-wavy because we understand that specific sites will have different situations that are concerning to them and we want to lean on the expertise of the site mods to understand what risks they see.

Answer (score 16):

While not per se against this experiment, I always had the idea that the threshold to vote was to prevent against "voting rings" where a user creates two accounts and then these accounts upvote each others posts.

While such rings of course still can occur, for example if one of the accounts gives a proper answer or asks a good question, it thus means one should at least put a (small) amount of effort into it before the carrousel starts.

If we automatically give voting rights when registering a user, it thus is quite easy to set up such a ring, even in an (almost) fully automated way. Whereas detecting and eventually removing the rings is less trivial.

Comment: the goal of voting rings is to inflate the reputation of 1 or more accounts, often for the purpose of getting out of a question ban or making spam look more credible or inflating the imaginary internet credentials of a user. Making it cumbersome to start one is certainly one effective way to prevent it, we do have an example to look back on with Teams where the ability to easily get a voting ring going using the association bonus from teams (which was silly to exist in the first place) caused problems.

Comment: When I say that using reputation to prevent abuse is a simplistic solution, that's what I'm getting at. Yes, sock puppets and voting rings are real concerns because, people do not necessarily use votes as we permit - sometimes they honestly assume it's "acceptable" while others do it after being told to stop repeatedly. This test is a sort of cost/benefit analysis of removing this solution. We don't *know* anything about how potential voters would vote.  We can guess. We can poke at unregistered and low rep user votes... but we can't actually know.

Comment: There are a lot of assumptions out there about the amount of tooling that would be needed to address the new issues caused. We could invest a lot of time in creating those tools and automations and making sure they work and then remove the reputation to vote to see what happens. Best case, we've built all the right things and no additional tools are needed and all invalid votes of all types are handled and  all is well with the site. This would be amazing but I think it overestimates our ability to predict human behavior. It doesn't allow us to test the impact on engagement.

Comment: The other end of things is we just make the change with no improvements in tools and figure out what we need based on the test, leaving the sites to deal with the issues. This would save us from building tools that we thought would be helpful but  ended up missing most of what they were intended to catch. It also ignores that we have existing tooling needs to identify vote fraud that mods have been really clear about needing. This is also higher risk as it could leave the sites unable to deal with issues until tools were built or would make rolling back the test more likely.

Comment: Our proposed test plan is in the middle of these two extremes. We're building improvements to tools we already know we need to address current levels and types of vote investigations and let mods use and suggest improvements to the tools to ensure they're useful. When the test starts, we hope the bulk of cases will be identified by the existing tools and, when they don't, we seek out the new cases and build tools specifically geared to them. While there is some risk, it's not as high as the prior option but we get data without first spending 6-8 months guessing what tools we need.

Answer (score 14):

This is just opening the flood-gates to users with no clue how the system works deciding on a whim, or mere capricious action, how a question is received; whilst having zero knowledge of how the SE structure is designed to work.

Unlike Facebook, the grumpy face icon posts don't just fall off the bottom of the interest list after a day or two, to never be seen again. This affects long-term visibility & usefulness as a future resource.

I'm really not sure about this idea, to put it politely.

I already think 125 rep is too low.
I would support that a consolidated network rep of maybe >50k could allow low rep users who have small sites to have additional privileges granted as a 'bigger' association bonus. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384293/276027 but I have no desire to see 'open season' declared.

Personally, on sites I have lower rep & less frequent engagement, or topics about which I have less knowledge, I am far more circumspect about my own voting; only voting when Q or A is clear to me with my limited grasp of a topic. I don't vote on things I don't understand.
Nor do I reflexively VTC as unclear - "Just because you don't understand something does not automatically make it unclear."

I have serious doubts new users would be so considerate.

Comment: While the SE model is certainly special, I don't think that the decision to vote here is some super hard-to-grasp concept; I think upvoting what's good and downvoting what's bad is pretty universal. I believe this experiment is useful precisely because there are so many strong opinions about how this will affect quality– either the cynical among us will be validated, or things will end up better than we imagined. Either way, lessons will be learned, and we can move forward better informed than we are now.

Comment: That aside, I also don't think YouTube is the best example; while you're correct about the public motivations of that change, the move itself has been pretty negatively received by most, in my understanding– YouTube removed a useful signal for quality because some people misused it some of the time, instead of building better tooling for creators experiencing the abuse. The change was a cop-out, IMO.

Comment: @zcoop98 YouTube removed a useful signal for quality because people used it for the exact purpose it was made for, to the embarrassment of corporate media.

Comment: @user3840170 I dunno. When any group does a "brigade" - telling all its members "hey go and downvote [or upvote] this object" - the upvote/downvote ratio on that object no longer correlates to audience perception the way it usually does. You seem to be claiming that it does still reflect audience perception which is embarassingly low, but it doesn't because it's now skewed towards the perception of that particular group.

Comment: @zcoop98 For this experiment to be useful, there needs to be measurable "fail" and "success" conditions to agree on beforehand. AFAIK there isn't, and as such any result could count as a success depending on how it is interpreted.

Answer (score 13):

Votes are something very important in the SE system. If SE is willing to reduce the rep requirement to upvote/downvote to the bare minimum (1 rep), I feel it's time now that all users get to see vote count of posts (number of upvotes and downvotes) regardless of rep.

Related request [Show the vote split by default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286897/show-the-vote-split-by-default)

Comment: What would be the argument for that?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286897/show-the-vote-split-by-default

Answer (score 13):

### Keep the old thresholds for meta

The ability to post on meta on most sites is locked behind 5 rep (except if you're asking about your post). Even users with five times that amount tend to not understand what meta is about, based on what meta posts they're creating (mostly questions that they couldn't ask on the main site, being question banned). I would prefer if we kept voting to either its original thresholds or at least something that's higher than 1 rep to keep meta as a platform for *active* users of the site.

For example, by coincidence, I saw a meta post of mine ended up on Hacker News (and from there, Reddit), and it ended up with a lot of views. However, reading the comments on Hacker News, most of the users were talking about Stack Overflow, which was not the site I posted on. I wouldn't want anyone to be voting on my post based on their opinions of what should happen on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 12):

If the rep barrier will be removed, maybe add a *time* barrier to prevent (some) sockpuppets?

- Either based on the age of the account ("created at least 1 month ago")
- and/or based on participation ("visited the site on at least 10 distinct days")

Of course the actual limits are to be decided.

That way a user cannot quickly create a sockpuppet account to upvote their own posts, but (provided the limits are not too high) a new real user can soon participate.

Answer (score 11):

I have concerns about how malicious users could exploit this change, but SE has heard those from me and many other mods already. In the end this will come down to how much effort SE will spend on mod tools and automated mechanisms to prevent abuse. I think most of this is fixable, it's just a lot of work. So in this answer I'll focus only on why I think that, if it can be done safely this change could be a good idea.

I do think it is worth to try this because the decline in voting is a fundamental threat to the Q&A model. Depending on which site and which tag on larger sites you post, voting volume in general can be extremely low. It's not unusual to post a reasonable answer or question and receive no votes at all. This is bad in terms of motivating users to post content, if nobody votes on it at all. It also means that essentially no real curation is happening there, you don't get any information what the community actually thinks about those posts. Okay, some of these are just meh posts and zero is an acceptable score for them, but for many of them it's just as if the voting system doesn't exist because nobody bothers to use it there. They are reasonably good or bad posts, probably not obviously excellent nor obviously terrible and they likely require some domain knowledge to distinguish if they're on the good or the bad side.

Post scores need a minimum level of voting activity to work. Giving more users the ability to vote will likely help with that and in the end add more signal to the post scores.

Comment: I'm kind of worried about roomba-ing capabilities. from my time on reddit (still ongoing), people write horrendously (compared to the standard of stack exchange) poorly defined, poorly researched, poorly titled questions, and many of those get net positive scores, which I think would be counter to the mission (make the internet a better place) and methodology (quality Q&A) of stack exchange.

Comment: "the decline in voting is a fundamental threat to the Q&A model" On the one hand, voting is kind of second nature after some time, i.e. to automatically and almost sub-consciously estimate the quality of content and decide if it falls into the up or down area. On the other hand it is real effort and quite boring to thousands of times think about how bad or good the content is. I'm a bit tired of it. It's kind of understandable that others should do the job instead but can they do it as good or are they rather just adding noise in the voting, even decreasing its value?

Comment: Historically, everything goes down over the years at least on SO, questions, answers, .... why should votes be an exception.

Answer (score 10):

> We have collected user research over the years indicating that many people have struggled to participate because they feel the restrictions about who can vote are too limiting and prevents them from indicating when questions or answers are good or bad.

That's assuming that they know when answers are good or bad. We have no clue if they know anything about site conventions or rules; the way that they demonstrate that they do is through getting reputation.

Voting is a major way that communities enforce their community expectations, and allowing people who don't know those to vote will substantially undermine that. It's like a country opening up voting to anyone in the world whether they live there or not.

It's already easy enough to abuse the voting system. Opening it up to people who know nothing about the site would remove one of the most important safeguards against abusive voting. For example, it would make sock puppetry and voting rings *vastly* easier to set up.

Also, most people with 1 rep have not contributed a single question, answer, or approved edit. That means that they aren't really invested in the site and won't vote in a way that's in the site's best interest.

Answer (score 10):

You claim to have "data" supporting that there's some kind of complaints about not being able to participate solely because of voting, etc.  The biggest question nobody seems to be asking is the elephant in the room.

### Where is this so-called data / "user research" for review by the community, community moderators, etc.?

During the past moderator strike earlier this year (2023), the intentions of StackExchange were called into fault over supposed "data" regarding moderators and the use of "AI detectors" blindly to filter on AI posts.  SE claimed to have "data" that took the striking moderators and wider audience *over a month* to get this data produced and provided by StackExchange for audience and independent review.  Ultimately, leading the data to not be helpful in StackExchange's argument, and ultimately calling into question the fidelity of StackExchange's claims whenever they refer to "data" that has not been publicly disclosed in any way (even anonymized) for analysis.

Like the claims made with regards to AI content handling which led in part to the moderator strike which ultimately led to the moderators who were striking to 'strong-arm' StackExchange into sharing their data on that situation, **a claim is being made about "data" here (emphasis mine)** without that data being visible/public in any way (even anonymized):

> We've long understood that many users find it difficult to participate on Stack Exchange in some ways. **We have collected user research over the years** indicating that many people have struggled to participate because they feel the restrictions about who can vote are too limiting and prevents them from indicating when questions or answers are good or bad.

Interpretation of this means that "user research" is a reference to collected "data" indicating that "people are struggling to participate" solely because of voting.  Which is not the case, and without the data being publicly auditable is unable to be substantiated and this is simply "hearsay".

Unless this data (even anonymized to protect the identities of those who contributed) is provided for independent reviews, **there is no basis** for SE to make any such arguments, and any such claims based on this research are as such hearsay.

Therefore, just like during the moderator strike, **it is of benefit to the community and its moderators and wider audiences to make this data public**, and **I would like to see this data in order to validate these "claims" made by StackExchange**.

Preferably, filters need to be put on this 'data' that exclude:

1. Sock-puppet chains where "users" are in fact sock puppets and not actual users (and the chains are used for abusive purposes)
2. Sock-puppet users of actual users (i.e. legitimate use sockpuppets that are not for voting abuse,etc.)
3. Known **problem users** who simply complain about everything just for the sake of complaining (CMs: you know the list of individuals I mean)

**Either way, can StackExchange provide this data so that it can be looked at and reviewed, even if treated as PII and only revealed to community elected diamond moderators?**

Comment: Hear, hear. Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. Also, I _can_ imagine that only a tiny number of people "leaving" SE will bother to fill out a form/survey or something to let SE know why they're leaving. The question then is — how representative _is_ that number? Also: what does it mean "a user has left"? Are we talking here about a certain plausible and measurable metrics such as "having not logged in for more than 30 days"? Of the total number of users in that category, how many have answered the survey? Where is the statistical analysis on that? Can it be peer-reviewed...?

Answer (score 9):

Arduino SE would be a great place to test this out. We only get a dozen new questions in a 24 hour period, so if the users with only one reputation point go wild, it would do little damage (assuming the reader thinks it would cause damage).

Of course, the reputation points are like the points on the Tell-Lie-Vision show, "Whose Line Is It Anyway". Everything is made up, and the points don't matter.

I did a survey of my local grocery stores, gas stations, restaurants, etc., to see if any of them accept SE reputation points as payment. I have yet to find any business where I live that accepts them.

See [Should Arduino SE participate in the '1-rep voting' test?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2750)

Comment: Whilst this may be true for everywhere except SO, there have been multiple reported cases of SO rep having meaningful value, with cases of people selling SO rep and SO rep amounts being listed as a job requirement having been reported in the past.

Comment: @user1937198 - Selling rep? Isn't that against the user agreement SE users sign?

Comment: It's against the user agreement,  doesn't mean people haven't tried it and force mod intervention.

Comment: Enough the mods put a policy on meta regarding buying/selling:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410831/dont-be-that-account-buying-and-selling-reputation-and-bounties other than that, no idea.

Comment: see cocomac's answer post about the association bonus. rep may not affect anything in real life (debatable, with people trying to get rep to put it on their resume), but it significantly affects the entire network

Comment: the focus here is not reputation, but posts scores

Comment: @Juraj - We definitely have low post scores on Arduino SE. It seems even the "regulars" don't want to take the time to vote on posts. Can you believe only 36 users have been doing all the voting on our stack this year to date? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=year If the new users with 1 rep can figure out the "mystery meat" links to up-vote/down-vote Q+As, then maybe post scores would improve.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion:

Letting users vote from 1 rep is opening sites very much to botting and spamming.

Giving that power to users that created their account 30 seconds ago would open the door to people creating 1000 accounts with bots and upvoting/downvoting something 1000 times.

But, counter proposal: If an account is already vetted on another site (lets say they have at least 200 rep on another site of the network) then yes, they can vote on 1 rep.

But an account that is brand new to the network cannot.

Comment: if you have 200 rep on any site, then you get 100 association bonus rep on all other sites (unlocking the voting privilege, which is typically 15 rep). your counter-proposal is already a thing.

Comment: [several answer posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A393127+is%3Aa+ring) have already brought up voting ring issues, and the question post already talks about it as well. I'm certain that that scale of voting fraud would be easily detected by the existing serial vote detection.

Comment: Account age is no guarantee it's not a bot.  On Facebook, bots will frequently create accounts, and then let them sit idle for a year in order to evade certain types of spam control, before abusing them.

Comment: @starball very true! Completely forgot about it.

Comment: @FuzzyChef I have the impression we could use it the other way even; an account that within a month has not enough score to even vote would be a redflag to me; but it could bring a bunch of false flags.

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR: Please prevent the *logical* network-wide effects that this experiment might have.

This is slightly similar to a [previous answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393129/2896919) about the association bonus posted on Sept 19 by cocomac.

While the proper control and contingency measures aren't implemented across the whole network during the experiment, please isolate the network from the side effects of this experiment on 2-3 volunteer sites with other Stack Exchange sites. The change in the voting dynamic will have a direct effect on the users' reputation dynamic; hence, the dynamics of how post creators earn privileges will change and the dynamic of how actions might be triggered:

- Association Bonus
- Hot Network Questions

---

## Association Bonus

The association bonus allows users to earn privileges like chat, comment anywhere and upvote on all sites across the network.

There is a debate about the reputation system in the comments on this question. A specific Meta Stack Exchange post about the reputation system has not been linked to this experiment. While this debate is relevant, there is no conclusion. Considering this, I'm asking that the sites not participating in the experiment be isolated from the possible overload that might imply this experiment due to the uncertain effect of the change in the reputation system dynamics across the Stack Exchange network.

Ref. [What is the association bonus, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/289691)

Rel. [The Stack Exchange reputation system: What's working? What's not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387356/289691)

## Hot Network Questions

The change in the dynamics of question scores from the participant sites in this experiment might impact Hot Network Questions, making the "competition" to appear on this list uneven. Sites like GenAI, which is also an experiment, have benefitted from getting questions on the HNQ and might be at a disadvantage against the sites participating in this experiment, reducing the probability of attracting viewers and posts through HNQ.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by isolating the network from the side effects of the experiment in relation to the association bonus? Are you suggesting that users who earn 200 reputation on the experiment sites should not receive the association bonus on other sites? That doesn’t seem fair to me if they earned the reputation legitimately, by contributing good/high quality content. After all, the experiment aims to increase participation and engagement in the SE network.

Comment: @galacticninja The isolation should be only if there aren't proper means to avoid the transitional side effects. Once the experiment finishes and decide that the votes be permanent the association bonus should be granted.If the CM Team will handle the moderation burn on non participating sites,  the isolation will not be necessary.

Comment: Even if the CM team allow for supporting other sites, it is worth considering that people may engage in abusive behaviors on the trial sites, specifically for the purpose of gaining the association bonus for stackoverflow to abuse SO. Which may result in a considerable burden, both on SO, and the trial sites.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to my points in my other answer, I would like to pose a question: what do you mean by "participation" in this context? Are you implying that lowering the voting threshold will cause people to be more likely to answer questions? More likely to ask questions? More likely to propose edits? Visit the site more often? More likely to register for an account? Or merely more likely to vote?

Comment: All of the above, minus the "merely" in the last one. Voting on its own is very important to the ranking of the content on the site. While *only* increases in voting (that indicate votes are being used appropriately) would be the bare minimum we'd hope for; all of the other things would hopefully be knock-on effects... I'm not necessarily expecting a huge bump in (honest) signups because the current UI for logged-out users is to show an account creation popup with only tiny text indicating 15/125 rep is required to vote. But for the other things, I think we're looking for change, yes.

Comment: Even if the people voting don't answer questions, the people who are and might be discouraged by having their effort go to waste might see an increase in votes leading to them posting more answers. For voters, they may be frustrated by not being able to vote and just write off the site because of it. Similar for question asking - though many sites see a lot of questions asked by less-engaged or new users, so I'm not sure there'd be as much difference. Someone who is more engaged because they don't feel gatekept out of the community might also edit or visit more often.

Comment: quoting the question post: "_we hope to spur participation and engagement - including posting, voting, and curation/moderation._". It's not obvious to me how cause leads to the desired effect here though.

Comment: "Participation" likely translates into "numbers we can use to appease our venture capital investors". Quality or usefulness of such "participation" *to the community* is of secondary concern (if it's a concern at all).

Answer (score 5):

We need more people voting in general. People who are new/on the verge of creating an account so their vote will count, people who've been here forever and lurk, and everyone in-between; it's what makes these sites different from an old style discussion forum. This change at least should introduce new users to voting sooner and open up a very large group of users to being able to perform the actions that the community at large for whatever reason isn't doing enough of.

I don't expect this to fix our voting problem overnight, but hopefully it'll be a change that improves the situation over time or at minimum lessens the decline.

I think this is generally a good change, if we can solve the one good thing that the existing solution actually does: make voting fraud less accessible to new users. Hopefully the solution we come up with to that makes voting fraud less accessible to *everyone*.

---

I'm seeing a lot of varied arguments against this that I disagree with:

> - Users often downvote because they don't understand the question
> - Users often vote without knowing the norms of the community
> - Users often vote not knowing what voting is for
> - The 125 rep cost allows the user to learn that using votes for revenge is wrong
> - Small sites might get overrun by people from the outside voting

Frankly, these users *are* part of the community and their opinions matter.

- A post being written in a way such that someone "doesn't understand it" is a valid reason to downvote, regardless of the user's experience level. These sites aren't meant to *only* serve users above certain level of expertise.
- Posting a question or answer and receiving an upvote doesn't teach me what the community at large values nor should I care what the community at large values. My vote is *mine.* If I find the post useful it'd be *wrong* to not upvote it.
- Earning 125 rep doesn't somehow teach me to better recognize what is and isn't useful. Again, my vote is *mine*, what the community sees as useful isn't relevant to the purpose of my vote.
- You don't learn how to be an adult being by earning 125 reputation on a stack site. No amount of delay before being able to cast downvotes is going to somehow teach people not to cast revenge votes or other votes for malicious reasons. Instead of preventing this by preventing voting in general, tools should exist to detect it and the punishment should be appropriately targeted.
- If people from the outside are voting maliciously, that's a problem for mods and staff to deal with. If we need more tools that will help identify when a sudden influx of previously inactive or new users are logging in and voting due to some outside source, they should be built and a policy should exist for dealing with this scenario. This isn't new, it happens all over the internet, it will *(and does)* happen here. Preemptively put tooling in place to detect it, however it may often require no intervention at all. These users are members of the community after all.

There's literally no benefit outside of preventing fraud from a select group of users for these tools to be so limited. Surely there's an opportunity here to create better tools for catching and dealing with fraud in general rather than relying on a solution that only targets one group of users. It'll also be easier to understand what tools are needed when we face them rather than constantly going in circles over what *could* happen.

Comment: "We need more people voting in general." I would contest that. We only need people who know something about the matter to vote. All others would just add noise. More voters wouldn't automatically mean better quality votes. And some questions or answers with thousands of votes rather don't need more votes. At some point the value of another additional vote is very small. What we really need are more votes from the right people on the right items where it actually makes a difference.

Comment: see, i adamantly disagree with that, because, the sole person who is in the best position to decide whether or not a given answer is useful is *someone who actually needs it as a solution to their problem*, not some "expert" user who has been on SO for 13 years. A pristine library full of things deemed useful only by "experts" is less useful than one full of things that people actually need/use.

Comment: Usage is surely one quality approximation but that has at least two problems. Not all voters really use all the content they are voting on and people can still simply use the wrong solution because it looked easier or what not. If there was a way to actually measure usage I would like it more. Until then I would trust the experts much more, would even like to give their votes a higher weight. I appreciate your disagreement though. :)

Comment: bsides, that's never been the system we've had anyway. Earning 10 rep doesn't magically make you an expert. We'll still have all of the existing tools for dealing with incorrect/wrong/low quality answers/questions that we have now. I do appreciate engaging with my post though, I made it knowing full well it's going to be a controversial take on it, ;) This change is one I've been pushing for for years.

Comment: People who have problems that they don't know how to solve are *terrible* at figuring out which of the proffered solutions is the best one. Not just on Stack Exchange but everywhere in the world.

Comment: 'A post being written in a way such that someone "doesn't understand it" is a valid reason to downvote, regardless of the user's experience level. These sites aren't meant to only serve users above certain level of expertise.' What utter nonsense. The C++ questions on SO that hit the HNQ are half incomprehensible gibberish to me because C++ has evolved so much from when I was using it. But they are comprehensible to the people who're supposed to be answering them - the C++ experts. The site may be for all expertise levels, but that doesn't mean that a particular question has to be.

Comment: @benrg Absolutely agree, that's why I think the accept mark should be done away with. I'd rather rely entirely on which answers have been the most helpful over a longer period of time.

Comment: @muru i'm not suggesting that I, as someone with no C++ experience, should be browsing C++ questions and downvoting everything i can't understand. Rather, if the question is so poorly written that someone who has that problem can't comprehend it... it isn't a clear, useful question. We're talking about new users here, not "experts" looking for questions to answer, since they typically aren't the ones that would be gaining the ability to vote with this feature.

Comment: But that's largely a straw man, @KevinB.  The complaint about people downvoting questions they don't understand -- or, often, *mis*understand -- is exactly about those people lacking the technical understanding needed to evaluate the question appropriately, not about the asker's linguistic skills.  Nobody is suggesting that *linguistically* incomprehensible gibberish is undeserving of downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something I'd be interested to see explored as an alternative: Giving anonymous votes some kind / degree of public visibility (while still being anonymous, of course).

Interface options:

- Make it a setting to switch between the two, or put it in a tooltip when hovering the vote count, or put it side-by-side (probably visually clunky and confusing), etc. I don't care too too much how it's executed right now.
- Allow sorting by votes with anonymous votes taken into account. You could even get fancy and let the user give anonymous votes a custom weight / multiplier for sorting- Ex. 0.5 the weight of a "real" vote.
- Or don't show the actual value of the vote count with anonymous votes counted, but at least still allow sorting with them taken into account.

Why: I can see the value of making votes only count for rep once you earn it as a privilege (to gatekeep bad actors), but personally, the only obvious reason I see not to let anonymous votes to be optionally visible to the public is that it would enable people to game their post to the top of that sorting option by sending requests from multiple IPs (Catija semi-confirmed that anonymous votes are per-IP-address (for two anonymous votes from the same IP, only one is counted)). But while that's not perfectly solvable, it's a mitigatable problem.

Mitigating "anonymous voting fraud": Ex. only take up to X (Ex. 1) votes (somehow pick them if more than X were cast) from one IP per given time period (Ex. a day or week), and in that time period, the median of the taken anonymous votes on a given post is taken as the one and only anonymous vote cast in that time period for the purposes of displaying anonymous votes. It's hecking complicated, but I think it would do a pretty good job at making gaming votes / "anonymous voting fraud" unattractive, while still making anonymous votes have a degree of meaningful visibility to the general public.

---

I'd also like for votes one cast with an account that doesn't yet have that voting privilege to be at least visible to the user. Ideally I think those votes would take "real effect" automatically once they gain the privilege to vote in that direction, but I can understand why that could be difficult / complicated with the daily vote limit and sudden load with handling any serial voting, so I can understand if that's not a good option. At least if a user can see the votes they cast even before they gained a voting direction privilege, they can go back and slowly cast "real" votes on them retrospectively.

Related: [Once I reach 15 reputation, will my old votes be taken into account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285181/997587)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good experiment ***if* the following are excluded**:

1. Removing the 1 reputation cost to downvote answers
2. Reducing the reputation required to cast votes in child meta sites to 1

#### Elimination of the 1 reputation downvote penalty would invite abuse and devalue upvoting

The elimination of the 1 reputation downvote penalty would invite abuse (downvoting answers other than your own, etc.) and devalue upvoting, which would be contrary to the experiment's goals to increase participation and engagement. It would discourage participation if there were more downvotes thrown around without penalty. The current top answer to the Meta Stack Exchange post “[Why do you lose reputation for downvoting answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15866/162827)", among other answers, explains this point well.

> The motivation behind it is to put emphasis on up-voting or not voting
> at all. This way, down votes will carry more weight and it will also
> prevent users from abusing the system by down-voting excessively.
>
> According to what the founders, Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky,
> discussed on an episode of the Stack Overflow podcast, they wanted to
> find a way to discourage users from down-voting for less legitimate
> reasons (say a pro-Java developer down-voting everything remotely
> related to .NET or the like).
>
> I have to admit, it definitely puts it into perspective to compare how
> many points you gain for other activities vs. the 1 point you lose for
> a down vote. It is effectively the smallest penalty that the Stack
> Overflow scoring system will permit.

#### Reducing child meta voting reputation thresholds would allow bad actors to influence site policy

SE communities use meta discussion posts to reach consensus and set site policy. If we lower the reputation required to vote in child meta sites to 1, users who have not participated enough on the main site could affect site policy by voting on meta discussion posts. This is not a good idea for several reasons. For example, it could facilitate “brigading” from other communities (such as those outside the SE network) to influence site policy.

> “Brigading” is a term that originated on Reddit for a coordinated attack by a group of users of an antagonistic subreddit (forum dedicated to a particular topic). The brigade would privately agree to “downvote” comments, either on a random or targeted basis, to deprioritise them in users’ feeds and effectively censor them. The meaning of the term expanded to cover all coordinated voting behaviour to make something or someone seem more or less popular than they actually are, and now it means all coordinated abusive engagement behaviour online.

<sup>- https://www.institute.global/insights/tech-and-digitalisation/social-media-futures-what-brigading</sup>

Comment: The potential abuse should be addressed by moderation tools, not by penalties to downvote.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim I think both the downvote penalty and moderation tools are necessary to prevent abuse. The downvote penalty for answers has been a part of the SE network for 15 years now. It serves as a deterrent for users who might downvote answers indiscriminately or maliciously. Moderation tools can help to address such abuse, but they are not a substitute for the downvote cost. I don’t see any good reason to remove the downvote penalty now and rely solely on moderation tools.

Comment: I know that for 15 years it was used as a deterrent for users who might downvote answers indiscriminately or maliciously. But maybe it is not necessary, if other tools to prevent the same exist ( or will be created). Note that downvote penalty also stops some users (especially with low reputation) to downvote bad posts because they do not want to lost their 1 rep. It is worth to experiment and monitor results rather than speculate.

Answer (score -1):

1 rep voting is bad for reasons outlined in

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393135/320796
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393133/320796
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393137/320796

In general, gaining reputation is an important educating and self-check step before being allowed to have effect.

---

Not sure if it's too complicated but

wouldn't it be interesting to allow new users to vote and only count their votes after they gather reputation themselves from other users who are not not new?

That both increases engagement for new users and prevents obvious drawbacks. It would be interesting to evaluate how this idea could be exploited and improved.

Comment: related: [Once I reach 15 reputation, will my old votes be taken into account?](/q/285181/997587).

Answer (score -1):

> To understand motivations for new downvoters, the first few downvotes from a <125-rep user would require them to explain their downvote - this information will not be posted anywhere, but will instead be collected by our research team and bucketed into categories so that we can better understand reasons people downvote. **While we expect that many voters may just enter gibberish**, we feel like we'll get at least some usable information.

The information entered by users when downvoting should be made public or at least made available to OP. This will serve multiple purposes. One is that the OP will get the idea about how the post can be made more useful to the community by addressing the concerns raised when downvoting the post. Second, if it is public, the community can flag inappropriate downvotes for moderator action. Third, users will be more cautious before downvoting knowing that the information will be made public and can be flagged if inappropriate. This will decrease the number of users entering gibberish descriptions.

Only the information entered for downvote will be made public. The identity of user will not be attached to the information when exposing it to community. Hence, the privacy will still be intact.

As a side note, I would love to see this extra step of describing the downvote becoming permanent part of Stack Exchange sites. It will be really helpful for new users to understand the reasons for down votes. On many occasions, users just downvote the post without leaving proper comments on why they downvoted or what could be improved. Having description will help user to improve their post or flag the downvote if its inappropriate.

Comment: This is very common feedback we get from users and I understand why. I am sympathetic to this. People requesting this sort of tooling often do want to improve their posts and don't understand why they're not being received well. Creating content here at the level expected by the community is not easy for everyone and there are a lot of places where we can improve that experience. While I am sympathetic to this, forcing downvoters to include explanations is often deemed concerning for a lot of reasons. I invite you to poke around on MSE or MSO, as I expect you'll come across it easily.

Comment: As it relates to this project. In my responses to another answer, I've already mentioned that I'd be willing to consider sharing excerpts of these comments with the sites - particularly to see if they agree with the reasons for downvoting - but making these available to the poster is very much out of scope for this. Your answer actually recognizes exactly why this is out of scope - moderation of these comments and adding tooling for that would divert focus away from the test to something that really needs to be understood on its own because core community is against this sort of requirement.

Comment: While I won't go into detail about why this sort of thing is difficult to implement well, I do want to point something out. You say that the comments could be flagged if they are rude - and that's very true. I see you recognize this would have to avoid adding the name of the downvoter as it would reveal who voted - kudos for that, most people forget it! One other aspect I'm not sure you're aware of is that responses to comments asking for improvements to posts are often hostile and rude themselves - this is why many people don't comment.

Comment: I think a separate test where we can really dig into the needs of both posters and voters and find a better way to handle this would be time well spent. I think that the status quo leaves both voters and content creators frustrated. In particular what I mention in the last comment. If retaliation or rudeness are primary reasons people don't comment, people who really want the feedback are negatively impacted even if they wouldn't retaliate or be rude. I want to understand what could lead to more feedback being shared - but *without* requiring it.

Comment: Existing suggesting to make downvotes explanation mandatory: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are requests suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-requests-sugges)

Comment: I’ve posted a feature request to make explaining reason for downvotes easier https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393416/prompt-to-specify-downvote-reason-but-allow-to-keep-downvotes-anonymous/ inspired by your answer

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure dropping the rep threshold for voting is such a good idea. However, I strongly believe that **eliminating the bias** towards upvotes is a good thing. That means:

- equal reputation cost for up/down-votes (not necessarly 0)
- equal reputation threshold for up/down-voting ability (not necessarily 1)

Right now, the voting system is heavily skewed towards upvotes, which promotes popular (fun / click-bait) content at the expense of useful content. As soon as enough people lay eyes on a post, you can bet it will get upvoted.

Note that I specifically don't suggest that up/down votes should have equal impact on the poster's reputation, as I believe it's a bad idea. A user who posted a poor question/answer should normally be able to undo the damage by posting a useful one, even if the useful one doesn't attract as many votes.

Answer (score -3):

I like the idea of testing 1 reputation voting. While it remains to be seen what side effects it would have or if I'd want it to remain long term, that's the purpose of a test.

There's obviously a risk of depreciating the value of highly voted answers if they aren't voted on by experts. However, there's evidence this can work as seen by [AskHistorians](https://old.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/), a community known for high quality answers to field-specific questions.

I'm curious to see how this plays out.

Comment: it's not clear to me why this experiment would cause highly-voted-on-answers to be less voted on by experts. can you elaborate on your thought process?

Comment: my interpretation was, by increasing voting in general, you're reducing the ratio of the votes that are coming from "experts", assuming we're calling users with high "reputation" within the tag experts, but, that's kinda "the goal" i think

Comment: @KevinB but it also says "aren't voted on by experts"

Comment: "this can work since it's essentially the same system Reddit uses" Reddit is known for high quality answers to specific domain questions? Then I just got it wrong all the time. I always only see highly entertaining content without much depth and there everyone can vote makes sense, but maybe not here. The experiment might be able to show that if the results can be interpreted in a clear manner.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution I've edited my answer to use AskHistorians as my example, a Reddit community known for high quality answers to domain specific questions.

Comment: r/AskHistorians does have high quality answers, but they achieve that by having mods who aggressively delete anything not meeting their standards, not by democratic voting.

Answer (score -3):

What's the current barrier for voting? 100?

<strike>Isn't that what you get for participating in more than one stackexchange community?</strike>

`+100 Association Bonus`

So what's the difference between giving 100 rep just for existing and allowing 1 rep voting?

[You need 200 in any other site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303118/1387205) to get the `Association Bonus` so you're technically not a newbie to StackExchange, which means that you shouldn't misuse the privileges up to 100 rep level.

Comment: go read your site's /help/privileges page... or [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/997587)

Comment: Ok, so 15 to vote up and 125 to vote down, with the Association Bonus that's 0 and 25 with 2 stackexchange sites and 0 and 0 with 3 stackexchange sites.

Comment: "_So what's the difference between giving 100 rep just for existing and allowing 1 rep voting_" you seem to be missing everything else that unlocks with 100 rep...

Comment: I'm not, this question is about voting so I'm ignoring other privileges, but sure , what's the points of having 1, 5, 10, 15, 50, 75 and 100 rep levels if just by having 2 accounts on different stackexchange sites you will automatically get all of those. Just give them outright.

Comment: Here's a way better answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303118/1387205

Comment: what does this even have to do with the discussion here?

Comment: We're talking about allowing users with 1 reputation to vote. I said it was irrelevant because having 2 accounts on 2 different stack exchange sites you would get a `Association Bonus` which would give you 100 reputation and allow you to vote anyway. You mentione the other privileges that unlock at 100 rep, which have nothing to do with the discussion. Then I found an answer that explans that the ´Association Bonus´ is only given when the user has 200rep in at least one site, which is why I say that was a better answer to my question.

Comment: having two network site accounts does not grant you the association bonus... did you read the thing you linked?

Comment: Are you reading my posts?

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, I think this is a bad idea (for reasons already explained in other posts).

If you want to increase engagement and - perhaps - highlight  quality answers, **how about allowing users above a certain rep level to have two votes?**

Some likely benefits of this include:

1. Allowing experienced and (generally) more knowledgeable users to have more input.
2. Making it possible to upvote twice a very good answer and upvote once a less good but still worthy contribution without putting them on the same level when one is better than the other.  *Note: I've lost count the number of times I've seen users on History SE comment 'I wish I could upvote this answer twice'*
3. Helping people who spend a lot of time in providing comprehensive, quality  questions and answers reap the benefits of their hard work.

This change *may* also help SE to keep older users active on the site (and there are a number of other things that could be done here as well).

Comment: This makes no more sense than allowing a certain class of people (for instance, those who had voted consecutively in the past 5 Presidential elections) to vote more than once for candidates they feel are twice as good as the others.

Comment: @KenWhite Err, a misleading analogy I think. High rep users have demonstrated an ability to ask and / or answer questions well. Voting multiple times demonstrates only that one can find one's way to the polling booth. Still, I appreciate your feedback (and any other downsides to this proposal would be welcome).

Comment: No, voting twice is voting twice. You're allowed a limited number of votes per election (one), and you're allowed a single vote per question/answer here for the same reason. Allowing multiple votes is fraudulent, because it allows a question's (or answer's) value to the site to be inflated. It also would defeat the entire meaning of the voting system here. The idea of fraudulently inflating value is no different than fraudulently putting an individual into public office because they have friends who can vote multiple times.

Comment: Agreed, one vote per person in an election, and everyone has the right to vote regardless of beliefs etc. in a true democracy. But SE is not an election, nor is it a political system. The right to vote has to be earned through reputation. It's a privilege. I'm simply proposing an extension of a system that's already in use. Multiple voting is only fraudulent if one is gaming the system (i.e. breaking the rules). Also, answers with inflated votes are far more likely to occur because of the Hotlist. I'm not saying my idea is perfect, but it may improve things a little.

Answer (score -4):

How about a macroeconomic analogy? It's likely to be an inflationary measure.

---

This is one of the "government" actions that can easily lead to an increase in the "inflation rate", due to the "printing" of more of the previously more limited "means of exchange" (here: reputation). It may also lead to a re-distribution of such "wealth" at random, including to the "undeserving poor", and thus disincentivize those "hard-working middle classes" that contributed most value to the "society".

Answer (score -4):

If  downvotes by  everyone will be allowed,   they require even  better understanding what are the reasons of downvoting. The following proposal doesn’t sound comprehensive and complete:

> “To understand motivations for new downvoters, the first few downvotes
> from a <125-rep user would require them to explain their downvote -
> this information will not be posted anywhere, but will instead be
> collected by our research team and bucketed into categories so that we
> can better understand reasons people downvote. While we expect that
> many voters may just enter gibberish, we feel like we'll get at least
> some usable information.”

There is an existing question about  making comments mandatory for downvoters
[Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are requests suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-requests-sugges). Even if it is not mandatory now, it is encouraged to leave a comment, explaining what is wrong with the  post. [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**If  downvote with rep 1 will be allowed**, it should be at least  allowed (my personal preference -required) for  **downvoters to leave a comment or upvote one of existing comments**(if the existing comment explains the reason for downvote). I.e. **users with 1 rep should be allowed to leave comments as well**

Btw, adding an **ability to comment for 1+ rep users** will be the useful way to increase new users participation. Current “chicken and egg” rules “you are not allowed to comment, and  you should not put as an answer, what should be a comment” imho is the most frustrating restriction for new users.

If the comments explaining downvotes will become mandatory, it will not need to keep current downvote penalty -1  , the necessity of explaining downvote will be a better way to prevent unreasonable downvotes.

Related [answer by Hem Bhagat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393127/if-more-users-could-vote-would-they-engage-more-testing-1-reputation-voting-on/393208#393208)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "popular" - as I wrote in comments on Hem's answer, there are many reasons we would be unlikely to ever *require* explanations for downvotes. One of the primary reasons that there's a 50 rep barrier to commenting is that it becomes a vector for spam that can go years without notice. I don't particularly want to allow or require comments on downvotes as it could lead to spammers downvoting and then leaving spammy comments. I'd be more open to a multi-select for low rep users that allows them to pick valid reasons to downvote without giving a free text field.

Comment: I understand that many people think comments for low rep users would be helpful and I have specifically avoided talking about comments in this post because I know it would be highly-controversial. What many people don't appreciate is that comments are a huge potential risk vector for spam. While new activity (questions, answers, edits) are is made visible on the front page of the sites for review by users, comments are completely silent. There's no review queue for comments that would lead to us being able to identify spam comments quickly and comment volume would make that tedious.

Comment: While I focus on spam abuse of comments, there are many other issues with simple misuse of comments, either to answer questions in a comment or using comments to post rude and offensive responses. While these latter ones exist today (spam doesn't) and deserve some attention, until we can identify a solution to these and other issues, comments will continue to be gated behind reputation. While I think there's a lot of complexity in removing the rep to vote, I think removing the rep to comment would be even more difficult.

Comment: @Catija You answered my question why current (relying on moderation) approach for fighting spam is different for posts and comments. Is it a good exercise for AI to identify spam or rudeness in comments?

Comment: Users have created several solutions for comment spam - or at least ways to monitor for it, including creating chatbots that post  every comment (or comments that contain certain content) into chat rooms. When I was a moderator on Interpersonal Skills, I got someone to create such a bot because the site had many controversial questions that often led to very late comments going missed containing abusive or offensive content. Users in chat would then flag the comments for mods to remove. While this worked on IPS, the volume on SO would be... impossible.

Comment: We also have a homegrown tool on SO that automatically flags content that is deemed rude or offensive. It's not very good. I think there's also third-party tools that can do this. Improving our in-house tool or getting a third-party one are certainly options but something we haven't prioritized yet - but it's unclear whether there are viable options for spam. Many comments contain links. The Charcoal user project could likely be a foundation for flagging spam in comments but they have not needed to expand to them since it just doesn't happen right now. :)

Comment: Here's some related links for the [Flagging Robot](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/09/the-unfriendly-robot-automatically-flagging-unwelcoming-comments/) and [Charcoal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically).

Comment: @Catija, I feel that you should separate business requirements and technical problems. Which reputation is allowed to comment is the business decision. How to figure out spam or rudeness, is a technical issue, that can be solved  by machine learning and  AI, and (hopefully)will not  require much manual moderation once trained.  Moderators should be involved only when someone flag incorrect deletion (or not deletion) of the comments

Comment: I'm not sure how separation makes sense if we absolutely won't remove the reputation required until we solve the problem. It's a business decision that a site full of spam and rude content is going to harm the reputation of the site.

Comment: I think have completely misunderstood what exactly about that linked MSE post is "popular". you got it the other way around... Also, I'm almost certain that what you are proposing will just lead to a flood of "this doesn't work for me" comments, which are **noise** and should not be posted in the first place (see [/help/privileges/comment](/help/privileges/comment)).

Comment: @starball, I’ve removed “popular” from the reference to “mandatory explanation”  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-requests-sugges .My interpretation is based on that the number of votes to the question  is more that for the answer, explaining current approach . Anyway my answer is about the relationship between reducing the downvoters reputation and need to to allow downvotes explanation. How to achieve it- should be in a separate discussion.

Comment: @Catija, I’ve extended your suggestion as a feature request: [Prompt to specify downvote reason but allow to keep downvotes anonymous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393416/make-downvote-reason-mandatory-but-allow-to-keep-downvotes-anonymous)

Answer (score -6):

Stack Overflow Inc surely knows:

- when a user asks a question and receives a reply from a high-rep user, or a well-upvoted answer, and reads it, but never upvotes it or accepts it,
- when a new user receives a quality answer but they downvote it (even though we are trying to help them) because it doesn't quite address their poorly expressed question,
- when a user asks a question but never responds to requests for clarification.

So surely, if Stack Overflow Inc really wanted to encourage good voting and general behaviour, it could remind *"errant"* users how to behave by Email (since you presumably have all users' Email addresses) or interactively, maybe before letting them ask another question or downvote another answer.

Comment: Among other issues with this answer, SO _certainly_ doesn't know "when a new user receives a quality answer but they downvote it".  If we could programmatically detect quality answers, we wouldn't need voting, and LLM chatbots would work a lot better.

Comment: @RyanM If SO can rely on 3 users with the *"Close a question"* privilege to deduce that a question should be closed, surely it can rely on a similar metric to decide an answer is likely of good quality - e.g. written by a user with, say 10,000 rep and upvoted by two or more users with 5,000 rep or some variant of rep + upvotes. Please also clarify what the *"other issues"* are. Thank you.

Comment: Reputation is, first and foremost, an indication of answer (or question) _quantity_, rather than _quality_.  A lot of thought has been put into moving _away_ from reputation as a gate for features; the last thing we want to do is add _more_ dependencies on it.  I've seen plenty of users with thousands of reputation whose answers are absolutely terrible (often plagiarized).

Comment: Additionally, how many "new user"s actually have the 125 rep required to downvote?  Also, voting is an individual expression of whether the answer was useful.  If it was not, then downvoting it is entirely appropriate; perhaps the answerer should have clarified the "poorly expressed" question before guessing at the answer. We need _more_ voting on answers, not _less_. 
 Another issue: how does one detect a request for clarification vs. any other comment?

Comment: I defer to your experience as a moderator in seeing and understanding users' behaviour. I still feel that SO could do more to encourage users to vote more.

Comment: @RyanM I'd say, every time you find one of those users with "thousands" of reputation and frankly terrible answers... well, report them :-) Oh wait, you're a mod yourself hehe :)

Answer (score -8):

I would rather question certain other issues like you can answer before you can comment, questions get closed before new users had the chance to improve, edits must be at least 6 chars and edit queues are always full etc.

Comment: Questioning is always welcome, but calling SO past its prime isn't very constructive. Answering comes before commenting because Q&A is the most important content on the site (commenting is secondary). Edits needing 6+ chars and the queue size go hand in hand– the limit is there to help cut down on tiny edits clogging the queue (more than already happens), and once you hit 2k reputation the restriction goes away (on each site). The queue being full is a more complicated issue, since reviewing is managed by the community... I think incentives should be greater, but it's a tough problem to solve.

Comment: @zcoop98 I agree and I will remove the unconstructive comment about my personal perception of SO's status.