# Add an option to sort answers by the viewer's previously cast votes

Tags: feature-request, answers, voting, sorting

Motivation: *When I sort by highest score*, what I really want is that by default, what other people found the most useful is at the top, because I'm in a mode where I want to find things that will be useful to me. *But*, I upvote the answer that is useful to me, and that I want to see again if I revisit the same Q&A page (which is not necessarily the top answer(s)). I downvote the answer that is the opposite of useful to me, and that I don't want to see again if I revisit the same Q&A page (which is not necessarily the lowest-scoring answer(s)). I don't cast votes on the rest. Time passes, and I revisit the Q&A. When I am in this mode, I want to see anything I previously upvoted at the very top of the sorting.

Implementation proposal: Add a new sort option similar to "Highest Score", but that first does a top-level sort by what vote I cast, and *then* breaks ties by score.

Nitty gritty details:

- I don't particularly care what happens for deleted answers- whether they are forced to the bottom (taking "actual" top-level sort priority), or whether they have sorting priority lower than what vote the viewer cast.
- For the sake of not doing sudden page relayouts that might disorient the reader, it would probably be better to not re-order until the page is reloaded (though I assume this is the current convention anyway).
- I would really like for this to be an available feature for logged-in users below 15 rep (without full voting privileges) as well, but might be another can of worms (see also bottom paragraph of [this answer post of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393604/997587))